# Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-widget, compound-drawables

I have added an image right of the text in an `EditText` widget, using the following XML:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
  ...
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:background="@layout/shape"
  android:hint="Enter place,city,state"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/cross" />
```

But I want to clear the `EditText` when the embedded image is clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext

Comment: If you are using `TextInputLayout` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940540/9723204. It's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 405):

Actually you don't need to extend any class. Let's say I have an EditText editComment with a drawableRight

```
editComment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                // your action here

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

we `getRawX()` because we want to get the actual position of touch on screen, not relative to parent.

To get left side click

```
if(event.getRawX() <= (editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width()))
```

Comment: @user2848783 how to set this in my left drawable?

Comment: Working after changed `event.getRawX()` instead of `event.getX()` @AngeloS

Comment: One note: replace "return false;" to "return true;" otherwise after ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_UP will not be fired.

Comment: a bit improved answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184120/androidhow-to-clear-an-edittext-by-cross-button-in-the-right-side/27832205#27832205

Comment: If you add padding you need to count that in as well as the `getRight()` gets the right of the TextView, which won't be the right of the drawable if there's padding. Adding `- editComment.getPaddingRight()` to the end of your `if` statement should work.

Comment: `public final float getRawX ()`Returns the original raw X coordinate of this event. For touch events on the screen, this is the original location of the event on the screen, before it had been adjusted for the containing window and views.

Comment: You should check for negative. `.width()` does not check if it is returning a positive number. I just wrapped it with `width = Math.abs(width);`

Comment: This does not work if the EditText's parent is not aligned with the left of the screen. You should use event.getX() instead of event.getRawX() and use editText.getWidth() instead of editText.getRight()

Comment: In my case it is not working! Here getBounds() `returns Rect(0, 0 - -1, -1)` . Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: This is mixing absolute positions "getRawX" with relative positions "getRight". If you set a right or left margin on the editText you'll see how this breaks as the click is triggered on wrong coordinates.

Comment: I created an extension function for this case:
`
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
inline fun TextView.onRightCompoundDrawableClick(crossinline f: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { _, event ->
        val DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.rawX >= this.right - this.paddingRight -
                    this.compoundDrawables[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].bounds.width()) {
                f()
                return@OnTouchListener true
            }
        }
        false
    })
}
`

Comment: What about the relative drawable position, Start, and End?

Comment: `View.getRight()` returns relative value. You should add position of the View to that to get it right. You get the absolute position of the view by `getLocationOnScreen(intArray)` and then getting the `x`: `intArray.get(0)`.

Comment: As mentioned before, the location of the view is not considered (rawX instead of X), so it'll only work when the EditText is clipped to the parent. The answer/link from Paul Verest improves this, but doesn't take clickable padding into account. If you like to include this, incl. some explanation how it works, then check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163977/2660216

Comment: Kotlin Extension's can be used here to make it look good & easy to use across the App.

`fun EditText.setRightIconClick(clickEvent: () -> Unit){
    setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.rawX >= right - compoundDrawables[2].bounds.width()
                ) {
                    clickEvent.invoke()
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    })
}`

Answer (score 85):

Very, very good, thanks to everyone who contributed to this discussion. So if you don't want to deal with inconvenience of extending the class you can do the following (implemented for the right drawable only)

```
this.keyword = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search);
this.keyword.setOnTouchListener(new RightDrawableOnTouchListener(keyword) {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrawableTouch(final MotionEvent event) {
            return onClickSearch(keyword,event);
        }
    });

private boolean onClickSearch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // do something
    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    return false;
}
```

And here's bare-bone listener implementation based on @Mark's answer

```
public abstract class RightDrawableOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    Drawable drawable;
    private int fuzz = 10;

    /**
     * @param keyword
     */
    public RightDrawableOnTouchListener(TextView view) {
        super();
        final Drawable[] drawables = view.getCompoundDrawables();
        if (drawables != null && drawables.length == 4)
            this.drawable = drawables[2];
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.view.View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && drawable != null) {
            final int x = (int) event.getX();
            final int y = (int) event.getY();
            final Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
            if (x >= (v.getRight() - bounds.width() - fuzz) && x <= (v.getRight() - v.getPaddingRight() + fuzz)
                    && y >= (v.getPaddingTop() - fuzz) && y <= (v.getHeight() - v.getPaddingBottom()) + fuzz) {
                return onDrawableTouch(event);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public abstract boolean onDrawableTouch(final MotionEvent event);

}
```

Comment: You should add v.getLeft() to x and v.getTop() to y in order to get the correct position.

Comment: Actually you should replace `v.getRight()` by `v.getWidth()`.

Comment: What about drawableLeft??

Comment: Where did your onClickSearch method receive it's event?

Comment: note that your fuzz factor should scale with the DPI, 10px in ldpi is something completely different from 10px in xxhdpi.

Comment: You have add "- v.getPaddingLeft()" to the first part of the if "x >= (v.getRight() - bounds.width() - fuzz)".

Comment: What is fuzz for? Please clarify.

Comment: It looks like `fuzz` effectively makes the tappable area a bit larger, making it easier to tap the small drawable.

Comment: "if you don't want to deal with the inconvenience of extending the class".  Really wish we as programmer would work to extend our frameworks to our specific projects.  If you need a component that acts like an EditText but supports compound drawable clicks, create one.  Why expose how it works by externalizing the touch listener.  Setting setOnTouchListener is not as clear as setOnRightIconClickListener.

Answer (score 29):

Consider the following. It's not the most elegant solution but it works, I just tested it.

1. Create a customized `EditText` class `CustomEditText.java`:

   ```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.graphics.Rect;
   import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class CustomEditText extends EditText
   {
     private Drawable dRight;
     private Rect rBounds;

     public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     }
     public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
     }
     public CustomEditText(Context context) {
       super(context);
     }

     @Override
     public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
         Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
     {
       if(right !=null)
       {
         dRight = right;
       }
       super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
     {

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && dRight!=null)
       {
         rBounds = dRight.getBounds();
         final int x = (int)event.getX();
         final int y = (int)event.getY();
         //System.out.println("x:/y: "+x+"/"+y);
         //System.out.println("bounds: "+bounds.left+"/"+bounds.right+"/"+bounds.top+"/"+bounds.bottom);
         //check to make sure the touch event was within the bounds of the drawable
         if(x>=(this.getRight()-rBounds.width()) && x<=(this.getRight()-this.getPaddingRight())
             && y>=this.getPaddingTop() && y<=(this.getHeight()-this.getPaddingBottom()))
         {
           //System.out.println("touch");
           this.setText("");
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);//use this to prevent the keyboard from coming up
         }
       }
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

     @Override
     protected void finalize() throws Throwable
     {
       dRight = null;
       rBounds = null;
       super.finalize();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Change your layout XML to this (where `com.example` is your actual project package name):

   ```
   <com.example.CustomEditText
       android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
       …
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:background="@layout/shape"
       android:hint="Enter place,city,state"
       android:drawableRight="@drawable/cross" 
   />
   ```
3. Finally, add this (or something similar) to your activity:

   ```
   …
   CustomEditText et = (CustomEditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
   …
   ```

I might be a bit off with the calculation of the touch bounds for the nested drawable but you get the idea.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I have heard that modifying the MotionEvent is discouraged practice, leading to undefined behaviour that would likely break on different platforms, so perhaps a better solution could be http://stackoverflow.com/a/6235602

Comment: @RyanM, I used `TextView` instead of `EditText`. I took the code and if I click on the `TextView` (not the icon but on any space on the `TextView`), the method `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` is called. So, I can implement `OnClickListener` for a usual `TextView` without any additional classes such as `CustomEditText`

Comment: @RyanM, Instead of using `this.getRight()-rBounds.width()` why not use `this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getCompoundPaddingRight()` ? Wouldn't it take care of drawable's padding and also get rid of the drawable's bound?

Comment: @RyanM how to change the image on touch of cross button click event?

Comment: Custom versions of `EditText` do not support proper widgets tinting when using appcompat on pre-lollipop devices. Use `AppCompatEditText` as a parent class of your custom EditText

Answer (score 27):

I created a useful abstract class **DrawableClickListener** which implements **OnTouchListener**.

In addition to the **DrawableClickListener** class, I also created 4 additional abstract classes which extend the **DrawableClickListener** class and handle the clicking of the drawable area for the correct quadrant.

- LeftDrawableClickListener
- TopDrawableClickListener
- RightDrawableClickListener
- BottomDrawableClickListener

---

**Point to Consider**

One thing to consider is that the images are not resized if done this way; thus the images must be scaled correctly before being put into the **res/drawable** folder(s).

If you define a **LinearLayout** containing an **ImageView** and a **TextView**, it's a lot easier to manipulate the size of the image being displayed.

---

**activity_my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="replace this with a variable"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_left_image"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_right_image"
        android:drawablePadding="9dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
package com.company.project.core;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_my );

        final TextView myTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById( R.id.myTextView );
        myTextView.setOnTouchListener( new DrawableClickListener.LeftDrawableClickListener(myTextView)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrawableClick()
            {
                // TODO : insert code to perform on clicking of the LEFT drawable image...

                return true;
            }
        } );
        myTextView.setOnTouchListener( new DrawableClickListener.RightDrawableClickListener(myTextView)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrawableClick()
            {
                // TODO : insert code to perform on clicking of the RIGHT drawable image...

                return true;
            }
        } );
    }

}
```

**DrawableClickListener.java**

```
package com.company.project.core;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This class can be used to define a listener for a compound drawable.
 * 
 * @author Matthew Weiler
 * */
public abstract class DrawableClickListener implements OnTouchListener
{

    /* PUBLIC CONSTANTS */
    /**
     * This represents the left drawable.
     * */
    public static final int DRAWABLE_INDEX_LEFT = 0;
    /**
     * This represents the top drawable.
     * */
    public static final int DRAWABLE_INDEX_TOP = 1;
    /**
     * This represents the right drawable.
     * */
    public static final int DRAWABLE_INDEX_RIGHT = 2;
    /**
     * This represents the bottom drawable.
     * */
    public static final int DRAWABLE_INDEX_BOTTOM = 3;
    /**
     * This stores the default value to be used for the
     * {@link DrawableClickListener#fuzz}.
     * */
    public static final int DEFAULT_FUZZ = 10;

    /* PRIVATE VARIABLES */
    /**
     * This stores the number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
     * included to account for the size of a finger.
     * */
    private final int fuzz;
    /**
     * This will store a reference to the {@link Drawable}.
     * */
    private Drawable drawable = null;

    /* CONSTRUCTORS */
    /**
     * This will create a new instance of a {@link DrawableClickListener}
     * object.
     * 
     * @param view
     *            The {@link TextView} that this {@link DrawableClickListener}
     *            is associated with.
     * @param drawableIndex
     *            The index of the drawable that this
     *            {@link DrawableClickListener} pertains to.
     *            <br />
     *            <i>use one of the values:
     *            <b>DrawableOnTouchListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_*</b></i>
     */
    public DrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int drawableIndex )
    {
        this( view, drawableIndex, DrawableClickListener.DEFAULT_FUZZ );
    }

    /**
     * This will create a new instance of a {@link DrawableClickListener}
     * object.
     * 
     * @param view
     *            The {@link TextView} that this {@link DrawableClickListener}
     *            is associated with.
     * @param drawableIndex
     *            The index of the drawable that this
     *            {@link DrawableClickListener} pertains to.
     *            <br />
     *            <i>use one of the values:
     *            <b>DrawableOnTouchListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_*</b></i>
     * @param fuzzOverride
     *            The number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
     *            included to account for the size of a finger.
     */
    public DrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int drawableIndex, final int fuzz )
    {
        super();
        this.fuzz = fuzz;
        final Drawable[] drawables = view.getCompoundDrawables();
        if ( drawables != null && drawables.length == 4 )
        {
            this.drawable = drawables[drawableIndex];
        }
    }

    /* OVERRIDDEN PUBLIC METHODS */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch( final View v, final MotionEvent event )
    {
        if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && drawable != null )
        {
            final int x = (int) event.getX();
            final int y = (int) event.getY();
            final Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
            if ( this.isClickOnDrawable( x, y, v, bounds, this.fuzz ) )
            {
                return this.onDrawableClick();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    /**
     * 
     * */
    public abstract boolean isClickOnDrawable( final int x, final int y, final View view, final Rect drawableBounds, final int fuzz );

    /**
     * This method will be fired when the drawable is touched/clicked.
     * 
     * @return
     *         <code>true</code> if the listener has consumed the event;
     *         <code>false</code> otherwise.
     * */
    public abstract boolean onDrawableClick();

    /* PUBLIC CLASSES */
    /**
     * This class can be used to define a listener for a <b>LEFT</b> compound
     * drawable.
     * */
    public static abstract class LeftDrawableClickListener extends DrawableClickListener
    {

        /* CONSTRUCTORS */
        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link LeftDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link LeftDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         */
        public LeftDrawableClickListener( final TextView view )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_LEFT );
        }

        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link LeftDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link LeftDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         * @param fuzzOverride
         *            The number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
         *            included to account for the size of a finger.
         */
        public LeftDrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int fuzz )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_LEFT, fuzz );
        }

        /* PUBLIC METHODS */
        public boolean isClickOnDrawable( final int x, final int y, final View view, final Rect drawableBounds, final int fuzz )
        {
            if ( x >= ( view.getPaddingLeft() - fuzz ) )
            {
                if ( x <= ( view.getPaddingLeft() + drawableBounds.width() + fuzz ) )
                {
                    if ( y >= ( view.getPaddingTop() - fuzz ) )
                    {
                        if ( y <= ( view.getHeight() - view.getPaddingBottom() + fuzz ) )
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to define a listener for a <b>TOP</b> compound
     * drawable.
     * */
    public static abstract class TopDrawableClickListener extends DrawableClickListener
    {

        /* CONSTRUCTORS */
        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a {@link TopDrawableClickListener}
         * object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link TopDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         */
        public TopDrawableClickListener( final TextView view )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_TOP );
        }

        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a {@link TopDrawableClickListener}
         * object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link TopDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         * @param fuzzOverride
         *            The number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
         *            included to account for the size of a finger.
         */
        public TopDrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int fuzz )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_TOP, fuzz );
        }

        /* PUBLIC METHODS */
        public boolean isClickOnDrawable( final int x, final int y, final View view, final Rect drawableBounds, final int fuzz )
        {
            if ( x >= ( view.getPaddingLeft() - fuzz ) )
            {
                if ( x <= ( view.getWidth() - view.getPaddingRight() + fuzz ) )
                {
                    if ( y >= ( view.getPaddingTop() - fuzz ) )
                    {
                        if ( y <= ( view.getPaddingTop() + drawableBounds.height() + fuzz ) )
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to define a listener for a <b>RIGHT</b> compound
     * drawable.
     * */
    public static abstract class RightDrawableClickListener extends DrawableClickListener
    {

        /* CONSTRUCTORS */
        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link RightDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link RightDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         */
        public RightDrawableClickListener( final TextView view )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_RIGHT );
        }

        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link RightDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link RightDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         * @param fuzzOverride
         *            The number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
         *            included to account for the size of a finger.
         */
        public RightDrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int fuzz )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_RIGHT, fuzz );
        }

        /* PUBLIC METHODS */
        public boolean isClickOnDrawable( final int x, final int y, final View view, final Rect drawableBounds, final int fuzz )
        {
            if ( x >= ( view.getWidth() - view.getPaddingRight() - drawableBounds.width() - fuzz ) )
            {
                if ( x <= ( view.getWidth() - view.getPaddingRight() + fuzz ) )
                {
                    if ( y >= ( view.getPaddingTop() - fuzz ) )
                    {
                        if ( y <= ( view.getHeight() - view.getPaddingBottom() + fuzz ) )
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to define a listener for a <b>BOTTOM</b> compound
     * drawable.
     * */
    public static abstract class BottomDrawableClickListener extends DrawableClickListener
    {

        /* CONSTRUCTORS */
        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link BottomDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link BottomDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         */
        public BottomDrawableClickListener( final TextView view )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_BOTTOM );
        }

        /**
         * This will create a new instance of a
         * {@link BottomDrawableClickListener} object.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            The {@link TextView} that this
         *            {@link BottomDrawableClickListener} is associated with.
         * @param fuzzOverride
         *            The number of pixels of &quot;fuzz&quot; that should be
         *            included to account for the size of a finger.
         */
        public BottomDrawableClickListener( final TextView view, final int fuzz )
        {
            super( view, DrawableClickListener.DRAWABLE_INDEX_BOTTOM, fuzz );
        }

        /* PUBLIC METHODS */
        public boolean isClickOnDrawable( final int x, final int y, final View view, final Rect drawableBounds, final int fuzz )
        {
            if ( x >= ( view.getPaddingLeft() - fuzz ) )
            {
                if ( x <= ( view.getWidth() - view.getPaddingRight() + fuzz ) )
                {
                    if ( y >= ( view.getHeight() - view.getPaddingBottom() - drawableBounds.height() - fuzz ) )
                    {
                        if ( y <= ( view.getHeight() - view.getPaddingBottom() + fuzz ) )
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 21):

Kotlin is a great language where each class could be extended with new methods. Lets introduce new method for EditText class which will catch clicks to right drawable.

```
fun EditText.onRightDrawableClicked(onClicked: (view: EditText) -> Unit) {
this.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    var hasConsumed = false
    if (v is EditText) {
        if (event.x >= v.width - v.totalPaddingRight) {
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                onClicked(this)
            }
            hasConsumed = true
        }
    }
    hasConsumed
}
}
```

You can see it takes callback function as argument which is called when user clicks to right drawable.

```
val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_text)
    username.onRightDrawableClicked {
        it.text.clear()
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

Its very simple.
Lets say you have a drawable on left side of your EditText 'txtsearch'.
Following will do the trick.

```
EditText txtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
txtsearch.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() <= txtsearch.getTotalPaddingLeft()) {
                // your action for drawable click event

             return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you want for right drawable change the if statement to:

```
if(event.getRawX() >= txtsearch.getRight() - txtsearch.getTotalPaddingRight())
```

Similarly, you can do it for all compound drawables.

```
txtsearch.getTotalPaddingTop()
txtsearch.getTotalPaddingBottom()
```

This method call returns all the padding on that side including any drawables. You can use this even for TextView, Button etc.

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTotalPaddingBottom()) for reference from android developer site.

Comment: I think this is a fine answer, except the part where true is returned everywhere. I'd suggest to return true only when the event needs to be consumed (the touch gesture happened in the right area).

Answer (score 13):

I think it is much more easier if we use some tricks :)

1. Create a **image button** with your icon and set its background
       color to be **transparent**.
2. Put the image button on the EditText and of coz the right hand side
3. Implement the onclick listener of the button to execute your
   function

Done

Comment: Used `RelativeLayout` to achieve proper positioning, just seems less convoluted than other solutions, and far less code to maintain.

Answer (score 12):

That last contribution's use of `contains(x,y)` won't work directly on the result of `getBounds()` (except, by coincidence, when using "left" drawables). The `getBounds` method only provides the `Rect` defining points of the drawable item normalized with origin at 0,0 - so, you actually need to do the math of the original post to find out if the click is in the area of the drawable in the context of the containing EditText's dimensions, but change it for top, right, left etc. Alternatively you could describe a `Rect` that has coordinates actually relative to its position in the `EditText` container and use `contains()`, although in the end you're doing the same math.

Combining them both gives you a pretty complete solution, I only added an instance attribute `consumesEvent` that lets the API user decide if the click event should be passed on or not by using its result to set `ACTION_CANCEL` or not.

Also, I can't see why the `bounds` and `actionX`, `actionY` values are instance attributes rather than just local on the stack.

Here's a cutout from an implementation based on the above that I put together. It fixes an issue that to properly consume the event you need to return false. It adds a "fuzz" factor to. In my use case of a Voice control icon in an `EditText` field, I found it hard to click, so the fuzz increases the effective bounds that are considered clicking the drawable. For me `15` worked well. I only needed `drawableRight` so I didn't plug the math in the others, to save some space, but you see the idea.

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.graphics.Rect;

import com.example.android.DrawableClickListener;

public class ClickableButtonEditText extends EditText {
  public static final String LOG_TAG = "ClickableButtonEditText";

  private Drawable drawableRight;
  private Drawable drawableLeft;
  private Drawable drawableTop;
  private Drawable drawableBottom;
  private boolean consumeEvent = false;
  private int fuzz = 0;

  private DrawableClickListener clickListener;

  public ClickableButtonEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public ClickableButtonEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ClickableButtonEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public void consumeEvent() {
    this.setConsumeEvent(true);
  }

  public void setConsumeEvent(boolean b) {
    this.consumeEvent = b;
  }

  public void setFuzz(int z) {
    this.fuzz = z;
  }

  public int getFuzz() {
    return fuzz;
  }

  @Override
  public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    if (right != null) {
      drawableRight = right;
    }

    if (left != null) {
      drawableLeft = left;
    }
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      int x, y;
      Rect bounds;
      x = (int) event.getX();
      y = (int) event.getY();
      // this works for left since container shares 0,0 origin with bounds
      if (drawableLeft != null) {
        bounds = drawableLeft.getBounds();
        if (bounds.contains(x - fuzz, y - fuzz)) {
          clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.LEFT);
          if (consumeEvent) {
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            return false;
          }
        }
      } else if (drawableRight != null) {
        bounds = drawableRight.getBounds();
        if (x >= (this.getRight() - bounds.width() - fuzz) && x <= (this.getRight() - this.getPaddingRight() + fuzz) 
              && y >= (this.getPaddingTop() - fuzz) && y <= (this.getHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom()) + fuzz) {

          clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
          if (consumeEvent) {
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            return false;
          }
        }
      } else if (drawableTop != null) {
        // not impl reader exercise :)
      } else if (drawableBottom != null) {
        // not impl reader exercise :)
      }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    drawableRight = null;
    drawableBottom = null;
    drawableLeft = null;
    drawableTop = null;
    super.finalize();
  }

  public void setDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener listener) {
    this.clickListener = listener;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I have implemented in Kotlin

```
edPassword.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            val DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2
            val DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0
            val DRAWABLE_TOP = 1
            val DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.rawX >= (edPassword.right - edPassword.compoundDrawables[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].bounds.width())) {
                    edPassword.setText("")
                    true
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Extending on the idea by RyanM I have created a more flexible version, which supports all the drawable types (top, bottom, left, right). While the code below extends TextView, adapting it for an EditText is just a case of swapping "extends TextView" with "extends EditText". Instantiation the widget from XML is identical as in RyanM's example, bar the widget name.

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition;

public class ButtonTextView extends TextView {

private Drawable    drawableRight;
private Drawable    drawableLeft;
private Drawable    drawableTop;
private Drawable    drawableBottom;

private int     actionX, actionY;

private DrawableClickListener clickListener;

public ButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ButtonTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    if (right != null) {
        drawableRight = right;
    }

    if (left != null) {
        drawableLeft = left;
    }

    if (top != null) {
        drawableTop = top;
    }

    if (bottom != null) {
        drawableBottom = bottom;
    }

    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        actionX = (int) event.getX();
        actionY = (int) event.getY();

        if (drawableBottom != null && drawableBottom.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.BOTTOM);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        if (drawableTop != null && drawableTop.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.TOP);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        if (drawableLeft != null && drawableLeft.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.LEFT);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        if (drawableRight != null && drawableRight.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    drawableRight = null;
    drawableBottom = null;
    drawableLeft = null;
    drawableTop = null;
    super.finalize();
}

public void setDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener listener) {
    this.clickListener = listener;
}}
```

---

The DrawableClickListener is as simple as this:

```
public interface DrawableClickListener {

public static enum DrawablePosition { TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT };
public void onClick(DrawablePosition target); }
```

---

And then the actual implementation:

```
class example implements DrawableClickListener {
public void onClick(DrawablePosition target) {
    switch (target) {
        case LEFT:
            doSomethingA();
            break;

        case RIGHT:
            doSomethingB();
            break;

        case BOTTOM:
            doSomethingC();
            break;

        case TOP:
            doSomethingD();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}}
```

---

p.s.: If you don't set the listener, touching the TextView will cause a NullPointerException. You may want to add some more paranoia into the code.

Comment: It seems your code is not working, I have just tested and nothing happens when I touch the drawable.

Answer (score 7):

its working for me,

```
mEditTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()>0){
                mEditTextSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_delete), null);
            }else{
                mEditTextSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_search), null);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    mEditTextSearch.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(mEditTextSearch.getCompoundDrawables()[2]!=null){
                    if(event.getX() >= (mEditTextSearch.getRight()- mEditTextSearch.getLeft() - mEditTextSearch.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {
                        mEditTextSearch.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Needs to subtract right padding, if any, for edit text when determining the start of the hit rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is quite old, but I recently had to do something similar... After seeing how difficult this is, I came up with a much simpler solution:

1. Create an XML layout that contains the EditText and Image
2. Subclass FrameLayout and inflate the XML layout
3. Add code for the click listener and any other behavior you want

In my case, I needed an EditText that had the ability to clear the text with a button. I wanted it to look like SearchView, but for a number of reasons I didn't want to use that class.  The example below shows how I accomplished this. Even though it doesn't have to do with focus change, the principles are the same and I figured it would be more beneficial to post actual working code than to put together an example that may not work exactly as I intended:

Here is my layout: clearable_edit_text.xml

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- NOTE: Visibility cannot be set to "gone" or the padding won't get set properly in code -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_x"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</merge>
```

And here is the Class that inflates that layout: ClearableEditText.java

```
public class ClearableEditText extends FrameLayout {
    private boolean mPaddingSet = false;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of this class.
     * @param context The context used to create the instance
     */
    public ClearableEditText (final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of this class.
     * @param context The context used to create the instance
     * @param attrs The attribute set used to customize this instance
     */
    public ClearableEditText (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of this class.
     * @param context The context used to create the instance
     * @param attrs The attribute set used to customize this instance
     * @param defStyle The default style to be applied to this instance
     */
    public ClearableEditText (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate () {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final EditText editField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_field);
        final ImageButton clearButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_clear);

        //Set text listener so we can show/hide the close button based on whether or not it has text
        editField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged (final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i2, final int i3) {
                //Do nothing here
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged (final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i2, final int i3) {
                //Do nothing here
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged (final Editable editable) {
                clearButton.setVisibility(editable.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        //Set the click listener for the button to clear the text. The act of clearing the text will hide this button because of the
        //text listener
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (final View view) {
                editField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout (final boolean changed, final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        //Set padding here in the code so the text doesn't run into the close button. This could be done in the XML layout, but then if
        //the size of the image changes then we constantly need to tweak the padding when the image changes. This way it happens automatically
        if (!mPaddingSet) {
            final EditText editField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_field);
            final ImageButton clearButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_clear);

            editField.setPadding(editField.getPaddingLeft(), editField.getPaddingTop(), clearButton.getWidth(), editField.getPaddingBottom());
            mPaddingSet = true;
        }
    }
}
```

To make this answer more in line with the question the following steps should be taken:

1. Change the drawable resource to whatever you want... In my case it was a gray X
2. Add a focus change listener to the edit text...

Answer (score 4):

Simply copy paste the following code and it does the trick.

```
editMsg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (editMsg.getRight() - editMsg.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use getX() instead of getRawX().  I think getRawX() only works if the view is on the left edge of the screen.

Comment: The calculation of the positions is wrong. Is mixing absolute coordinates "getRawX()", with relative ones like "getRight()"

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous solutions worked for me in **Xamarin Android**. I was able to get the right drawable click listener working using the following:

**Create the following `OnEditTextTouch` event listener:**

```cs
  private void OnEditTextTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var rightDrawable = _autoCompleteTextViewSearch.GetCompoundDrawables()[2];

        if (rightDrawable == null || e.Event.Action != MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            e.Handled = false;

            return;
        }

        if (e.Event.GetX() >= _autoCompleteTextViewSearch.Width - _autoCompleteTextViewSearch.TotalPaddingRight)
        {
            // Invoke your desired action here.

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // Forward the event along to the sender (crucial for default behaviour)
        (sender as AutoCompleteTextView)?.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
    }
```

**Subscribe to the Touch event:**

```cs
_autoCompleteTextViewSearch.Touch += OnEditTextTouch;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've taked the solution of @AZ_ and converted it in a kotlin extension function:

So copy this in your code:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
fun EditText.setDrawableRightTouch(setClickListener: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { _, event ->
        val DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0
        val DRAWABLE_TOP = 1
        val DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2
        val DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.rawX >= this.right - this.compoundDrawables[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].bounds.width()
            ) {
                setClickListener()
                return@OnTouchListener true
            }
        }
        false
    })
}
```

You can use it just calling the `setDrawableRightTouch` function on your `EditText`:

```
yourEditText.setDrawableRightTouch {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Hats off Extension functions. thanks @mattia

Answer (score 4):

A probable solution to the above problem could be using android's new material component [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/searchInput"
                    style="@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/search"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconContentDescription="Search"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_search"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here the TextInputLayout attribute [endIconMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconMode(int)) when set, places a button at the end of the enclosed EditText.

Additionally `app:endIconMode = "custom"` allows customization of the icon's click functonality

Finally to listen to the end icon clicks call [setEndIconClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) on the enclosing TextInputLayout component.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Drawable drawableObj = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_btn);
        int drawableWidth = drawableObj.getIntrinsicWidth();

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        if (event != null && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (x >= (searchPanel_search.getWidth() - drawableWidth - searchPanel_search.getPaddingRight())
                    && x <= (searchPanel_search.getWidth() - searchPanel_search.getPaddingRight())

                    && y >= searchPanel_search.getPaddingTop() && y <= (searchPanel_search.getHeight() - searchPanel_search.getPaddingBottom())) {

                getSearchData();
            }

            else {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(searchPanel_search, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

and if drawable is on the left, this will help you. (for those work with RTL layout)

```
 editComment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getRawX() <= (searchbox.getLeft() + searchbox.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width())) {
                                     // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is mixing absolute positions "getRawX" with relative positions "getRight". If you set a right or left margin on the editText you'll see how this breaks as the click is triggered on wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

It is all great but why not to make it really simple?

I have faced with that also not so long ago...and android touchlistiner works great but gives limitation in usage..and I came to another solution and I hope that will help you:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/zero_row">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_round_corners"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:onClick="OnDatabaseSearchEvent" />
            <EditText
                android:minHeight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_round_corners"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Search.."
                android:textColorHint="@color/AndroidWhite"
                android:textColor="@color/AndroidWhite"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/e_d_search"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/AndroidWhite"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_oculi_remove2"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:onClick="onSearchEditTextCancel" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"-->
        <!--android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_oculi_remove2"-->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
Now you can create ImageClick listener or event and do what ever you want with text. This edittext_round_corners.xml file

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.2"
            android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:angle="270"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.7dp"
            android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts.

Comment: I have never used that for multi-line search, so sorry I never thought that this problem may appear. Probably blocking for multi line will help. Can you attach screenshot of app or view to see what happens? And I will try to resolved that and maybe help you (fix this code) and me for future use.
Thanks.

Comment: It's very easy to replicate, it even happens on the layout preview as soon as you add 2 lines.

Comment: A background for `EditText` should be `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have ImageButton on Right of edit text and give negative layout margin to overlap with edit text. Set listener on ImageButton and perform operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_status_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_box_blank"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/statusnote"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/note_del"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts

Answer (score 1):

Compound drawables are not supposed to be clickable. 
It is cleaner to use separate views in a horizontal LinearLayout and use a click handler on them.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:translationZ="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_map"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/search_edit"
            style="@style/EditText.Registration.Map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_location_search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location_gps_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/selector_ic_gps"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who does not want to implement the monstrous click handling. You can achieve the same with a `RelativeLayout`. With that you even have free handling of the positioning of the drawable.

```
  <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
     <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_undo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The `ImageView` position will be the same as you would use `drawableEnd` - plus you don't need all the touch listener handling. Just a click listener for the `ImageView` and you are good to go.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts

Answer (score 1):

This works fro me:) may this help you as well

```
edit_account_name.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (event.getRawX() >= (edit_account_name.getRight())) {
                    //clicked
                   return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is mixing absolute positions "getRawX" with relative positions "getRight". If you set a right or left margin on the editText you'll see how this breaks as the click is triggered on wrong coordinates.

Comment: i have added right margin on edit text, my code still works perfect

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several solutions but I wasn't convinced by any of them. Either very complicated or too simple (non-reusable).

This is my favourite approach at the moment:

```
mEditText.setOnTouchListener(
        new OnEditTextRightDrawableTouchListener(mEditText) {
          @Override
          public void OnDrawableClick() {
            // The right drawable was clicked. Your action goes here.
          }
        });
```

And this is the reusable touch listener:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class OnEditTextRightDrawableTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

  private final EditText mEditText;

  public OnEditTextRightDrawableTouchListener(@NonNull final EditText editText) {
    mEditText = editText;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT_POSITION = 2;
      final Drawable drawable = mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT_POSITION];
      if (drawable != null) {
        final float touchEventX = motionEvent.getX();
        final int touchAreaRight = mEditText.getRight();
        final int touchAreaLeft = touchAreaRight - drawable.getBounds().width();
        if (touchEventX >= touchAreaLeft && touchEventX <= touchAreaRight) {
          view.performClick();
          OnDrawableClick();
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public abstract void OnDrawableClick();
}
```

[You can look at the Gist here.](https://gist.github.com/Sottti/482059eb00e74030800e94d7162d2766)

Answer (score 1):

**Follow below code for drawable right,left,up,down click:**

```
edittextview_confirmpassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= (edittextview_confirmpassword.getRight() - edittextview_confirmpassword.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                // your action here                    edittextview_confirmpassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            edittextview_confirmpassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is more elegant way:
Don't use `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableEnd` in the `TextInputEditText`.

Instead you can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```

and then use the `endIconOnClickListener`:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
  // Respond to end icon presses
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940540/13545849

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple solution, just place `ImageButton` over `EditText`:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"/>

  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageViewSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**for left drawable click listener**

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getRawX() <= (txt
                        .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width() +
                        txt.getPaddingLeft() +
                        txt.getLeft())) {

                          //TODO do code here
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is mixing absolute positions "getRawX" with relative positions "getRight". If you set a right or left margin on the editText you'll see how this breaks as the click is triggered on wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a way for drawable left!
I tried this code and works.

```
txtsearch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            int start=txtsearch.getSelectionStart();
            int end=txtsearch.getSelectionEnd();
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() <= (txtsearch.getLeft() + txtsearch.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width())) {
                    //Do your action here
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is mixing absolute positions "getRawX" with relative positions "getRight". If you set a right or left margin on the editText you'll see how this breaks as the click is triggered on wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented @aristo_sh answer in Mono.Droid (Xamarin), since it's a delegate anonymous method you can't return true or false you have to take take of e.Event.Handled. I am also hiding the keyboard on click

```
editText.Touch += (sender, e) => {
                    e.Handled = false;
                    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
                    {
                        if (e.Event.RawX >= (bibEditText.Right - (bibEditText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2]).Bounds.Width()))
                        {
                            SearchRunner();
                            InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
                            manager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my generalized solution for handling TextView compound drawable click and touch events.

First we need a touch event handler:

```
/**
 * Handles compound drawable touch events.
 * Will intercept every event that happened inside (calculated) compound drawable bounds, extended by fuzz.
 * @see TextView#getCompoundDrawables()
 * @see TextView#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)
 */
public abstract class CompoundDrawableTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "CmpDrawableTouch";

    private final int fuzz;

    public static final int LEFT = 0;
    public static final int TOP = 1;
    public static final int RIGHT = 2;
    public static final int BOTTOM = 3;
    private static final int[] DRAWABLE_INDEXES = {LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM};

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public CompoundDrawableTouchListener() {
        this(0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with fuzz
     * @param fuzz desired fuzz in px
     */
    public CompoundDrawableTouchListener(int fuzz) {
        this.fuzz = fuzz;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!(view instanceof TextView)) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "attached view is not instance of TextView");
            return false;
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        for (int i : DRAWABLE_INDEXES) {
            if (drawables[i] == null) continue;
            Rect bounds = getRelativeBounds(i, drawables[i], textView);
            Rect fuzzedBounds = addFuzz(bounds);

            if (fuzzedBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                MotionEvent relativeEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    event.getDownTime(),
                    event.getEventTime(),
                    event.getAction(),
                    event.getX() - bounds.left,
                    event.getY() - bounds.top,
                    event.getMetaState());
                return onDrawableTouch(view, i, bounds, relativeEvent);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates compound drawable bounds relative to wrapping view
     * @param index compound drawable index
     * @param drawable the drawable
     * @param view wrapping view
     * @return {@link Rect} with relative bounds
     */
    private Rect getRelativeBounds(int index, @NonNull Drawable drawable, View view) {
        Rect drawableBounds = drawable.getBounds();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();

        switch (index) {
            case LEFT:
                bounds.offsetTo(view.getPaddingLeft(),
                    view.getHeight() / 2 - bounds.height() / 2);
                break;

            case TOP:
                bounds.offsetTo(view.getWidth() / 2 - bounds.width() / 2,
                    view.getPaddingTop());
                break;

            case RIGHT:
                bounds.offsetTo(view.getWidth() - view.getPaddingRight() - bounds.width(),
                    view.getHeight() / 2 - bounds.height() / 2);
                break;

            case BOTTOM:
                bounds.offsetTo(view.getWidth() / 2 - bounds.width() / 2,
                    view.getHeight() - view.getPaddingBottom() - bounds.height());
                break;
        }

        return bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Expands {@link Rect} by given value in every direction relative to its center
     * @param source given {@link Rect}
     * @return result {@link Rect}
     */
    private Rect addFuzz(Rect source) {
        Rect result = new Rect();
        result.left = source.left - fuzz;
        result.right = source.right + fuzz;
        result.top = source.top - fuzz;
        result.bottom = source.bottom + fuzz;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Compound drawable touch-event handler
     * @param v wrapping view
     * @param drawableIndex index of compound drawable which recicved the event
     * @param drawableBounds {@link Rect} with compound drawable bounds relative to wrapping view.
     * Fuzz not included
     * @param event event with coordinated relative to wrapping view - i.e. within {@code drawableBounds}.
     * If using fuzz, may return negative coordinates.
     */
    protected abstract boolean onDrawableTouch(View v, int drawableIndex, Rect drawableBounds, MotionEvent event);
}
```

Now you can process any touch events on any compound drawable of any TextView you like this way:

```
textView1.setOnTouchListener(new CompoundDrawableTouchListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onDrawableTouch(View v, int drawableIndex, Rect drawableBounds, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.textView1:
                        switch(drawableIndex) {
                            case CompoundDrawableTouchListener.RIGHT:
                                doStuff();
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Only interested in clicks? Just filter out by MotionEvent action:

```
/**
 * Handles compound drawable click events.
 * @see TextView#getCompoundDrawables()
 * @see TextView#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)
 * @see CompoundDrawableTouchListener
 */
public abstract class CompoundDrawableClickListener extends CompoundDrawableTouchListener {

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public CompoundDrawableClickListener() {
        super();
    }

     /**
     * Constructor with fuzz
     * @param fuzz desired fuzz in px
     */
    public CompoundDrawableClickListener(int fuzz) {
        super(fuzz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDrawableTouch(View v, int drawableIndex, Rect drawableBounds, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) onDrawableClick(v, drawableIndex);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Compound drawable touch-event handler
     * @param v wrapping view
     * @param drawableIndex index of compound drawable which recicved the event
     */
    protected abstract void onDrawableClick(View v, int drawableIndex);
}
```

Again we can easily handle clicks on any compound drawable of any TextView:

```
textView1.setOnTouchListener(new CompoundDrawableClickListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onDrawableClick(View v, int drawableIndex) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.textView1:
                        switch(drawableIndex) {
                            case CompoundDrawableTouchListener.RIGHT:
                                doStuff();
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope you liked it as I did. I will try to keep it updated here and in [related gist](https://gist.github.com/amaksoft/dbfb0fa827619dcb64b6a587efde34d9) if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple custom touch listener class instead of a custom EditText

```
public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private EditText editText;

public MyTouchListener(EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;

    setupDrawable(this.editText);
}

private void setupDrawable(final EditText editText) {
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()>0)
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, R.drawable.clearicon,0);
            else
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, 0,0);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2]!=null){
            if(event.getX() >= (editText.getRight()- editText.getLeft() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

There will be no drawable when the EditText is blank. A drawable will show when we started editing for clear the EditText.

You can just set the touch listener

mEditText.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(mEditText));

Comment: It's a little bit confusing that s TouchListener is handling the drawable visibility and the clear action itself. That's not a touch listener responsibility and the name of the class is misleading. As well as you are calculating relative positions is not necessary to remove margins from the equation. getRight - width will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions above work, but they have side affect. If you have an EditText with right drawable like

[image]

you will get a PASTE button after every click at the drawable. See [How to disable paste in onClickListener for the Drawable right of an EditText Android (inside icon EditText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411717/how-to-disable-paste-in-onclicklistener-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext-and/51513819#51513819).

Answer (score 0):

So many solutions, but none worked for me when I had two fields in a row.
This is drop in solution for adding clear button to edit text, worked for me in my situations where I have two fields or one field in a row. Written in kotlin !

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
fun <T : EditText> T.withClear(): T {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                    if (editable.isNotEmpty()) abc_ic_clear_material else 0, 0)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) = Unit
    })

    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.action == ACTION_UP && event.x >= (right - this.compoundPaddingRight)) {
            setText("")
            return@setOnTouchListener true
        }
        false
    }
    return this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apply a short solution that is suitable even for fragments of dialogue.

[image]

```
            //The listener of a drawableEnd button for clear a TextInputEditText
            textValue.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        final TextView textView = (TextView)v;
                        if(event.getX() >= textView.getWidth() - textView.getCompoundPaddingEnd()) {
                            textView.setText(""); //Clear a view, example: EditText or TextView
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_text"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilver">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/tiet_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:hint="@string/rep_hint"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_attach_photo"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilver"
                      />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/right_button"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:background="@color/clear" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using spannable textview buffer could be a solution. Look at this short and to the point tutorial:  For one it is much easier to do click events

https://android-designing.blogspot.com/2017/01/spannable-textview-with-image-clickable.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one is a good method, suggested by Hardik4560 ,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135554/7184172

Answer (score 0):

// Click Right Icon

[image]

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= (createEventBinding.etAddressLine1.getRight() - createEventBinding.etAddressLine1.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        // your action here

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right icon click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    final TextView mTvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle1);

    mTvTitle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() <= (mTvTitle.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width()))  {
                    // your action here
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DeAddExpences.this,DeHomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Make return true otherwise action will not perform.