# How can I mask the summary of an EditTextPreference when it is a masked password field?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-preferences

I'm using an `onPreferenceChangeListener` attached to my `EditTextPreference` that shows the value of the preference in the summary. Here's what it looks like:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference prePreference, Object objValue) {
    if (prePreference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        //TODO: Check if password type and show chacraters
        prePreference.setSummary(objValue.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the field is a masked password field, I'd like to show the default password mask characters in the the summary. Here's an example of a masked field:

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:key="password"
        android:title="@string/password" />
```

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want is the method to get the system's mask character(i.e., '.' by default)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like:

```
EditText edit = ((EditTextPreference) prePreference).getEditText();
String pref = edit.getTransformationMethod().getTransformation(objValue.toString(), edit).toString();
prePreference.setSummary(pref);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier yet, don't call the generated `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue` (which in turn calls `setSummary`) for the password preference.

Note that you shouldn't be storing passwords in the preferences, but instead prompt from a password when you need it, obtain a token from the service, and store the token instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the text size and put the characters in the textview for each integer in text size? Or did I misunderstand you?

Or take a look at this link:

[Hide password/viewpassword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685867/2728408)