# Visible password with TextInputLayouts passwordToggleEnabled

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am using a TextInputLayout with the new function from the Support Library: passwordToggleEnabled. This gives a nice "eye"-icon that lets the user toggle password visibility on and off.

My question is if there is a way to use this functionality but start with password visible?

My xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password_edit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The toggle looks similar to this:
[image]

I have not found a way to do this in xml, and not a way to manually toggle the visibility after the view is rendered. If I set the input type of the EditText to textVisiblePassword, the toggle is not shown. If I do it in code using for instance mPasswordEditText.setTransformationMethod(null); the password is shown but the toggle is gone and the user can't hide the password again. I know I can do it all manually but just wondering if I can make it work with the new magic toggle

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27050480/7329597 Hope it helps you :)

Comment: You have to check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27050480/7329597 Hope it helps.:)

Comment: @SejalBell - this is for manually showing or hiding password. But it doesn't work with TextInputLayouts new automatic toggle. If I set Input type to visible password as the answer suggests, the toggle button is gone. I want to show the password as default, but allow the user to hide it again.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to achieve this too, without trying to extend the class directly from the AOSP

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Have you figured out how?

Comment: @JoshuaTree Although I am too late, I am with my answer with detailed analysis. Take a look.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Working solutions added. Take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is below  <sup>*Another solution is at last of this answer*</sup>

```
private void setupPasswordToggleView() {
    final TextInputLayout textInputLayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.password);

    // You can skip post-call and write directly the code which is inside run method.
    // But to be safe (as toggle-view is child of TextInputLayout, post call
    // has been added.
    textInputLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CheckableImageButton passwordToggleView = textInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
            // passwordToggleView.toggle(); // Can not use as restricted to use same library group
            // passwordToggleView.setChecked(true); // Can not use as restricted to use same library group
            passwordToggleView.performClick();
        }
    });
}
```

---

> Now let me explain the answer

While looking into code of [`TextInputLayout.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java) I found that, there is a layout `design_text_input_password_icon.xml` which is being added to [`TextInputLayout.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java). Below is that code

```
private void updatePasswordToggleView() {
    if (mEditText == null) {
        // If there is no EditText, there is nothing to update
        return;
    }
    if (shouldShowPasswordIcon()) {
        if (mPasswordToggleView == null) {
            mPasswordToggleView = (CheckableImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.design_text_input_password_icon, mInputFrame, false);
            mPasswordToggleView.setImageDrawable(mPasswordToggleDrawable);
            mPasswordToggleView.setContentDescription(mPasswordToggleContentDesc);
            mInputFrame.addView(mPasswordToggleView); // << HERE IS THAT
            .........
}
```

Now next target was to find `design_text_input_password_icon.xml` and lookup id of the toggle view. So found the layout [design_text_input_password_icon.xml here](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/support/design/res/layout/design_text_input_password_icon.xml) and it has written as

```
18<android.support.design.widget.CheckableImageButton
19    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
20    android:id="@+id/text_input_password_toggle"
21    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
22    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
23    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end|right"
24    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
25    android:minHeight="48dp"
26    android:minWidth="48dp"/>
```

I found the id `text_input_password_toggle` of that view and now everything was easy to just find that view in it's viewgroup and perform action on that.

---

Another solution would be to iterate childs of `TextInputLayout` and check if it is `CheckableImageButton` and then perform click on it. By this way there would not be dependancy on id of that view and if Android changes the id of view, our solution will still work. (Although they do not change id of a view in normal cases).

```
private void setupPasswordToggleViewMethod2() {
    final TextInputLayout textInputLayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.password);

    textInputLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            View toggleView = findViewByClassReference(textInputLayout, CheckableImageButton.class);
            if (toggleView != null) {
                toggleView.performClick();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Where `findViewByClassReference(View rootView, Class<T> clazz)` <sup>[original utility class](http://upshots.org/android/android-find-views-children-by-class)</sup> is defined as below

```
public static <T extends View> T findViewByClassReference(View rootView, Class<T> clazz) {
    if(clazz.isInstance(rootView)) {
        return clazz.cast(rootView);
    }
    if(rootView instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) rootView;
        for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            T match = findViewByClassReference(child, clazz);
            if(match != null) {
                return match;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Some comment on your first solution - `R.id.text_input_password_toggle` is not a public id.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Solution I posted a few days ago finds the view without using the id, using the content description instead

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I did not get public-id concept. And if you are talking about the id which is declared in the layout created by Android itself, then I would say that is fine to use that id if you know and your solution will work until they do not change the id. This is similar to the old-styled listview example where we were giving id of listview what was declared by android. And there are many examples where we use such ids. But can you please explain public-id if I did not get it?

Comment: In 2019, there's a public method called `passwordVisibilityToggleRequested()` on `TextInputLayout` that does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

With the Material Components Library (`1.1.0` , `1.2.0-beta01`, `1.3.0-alpha01`) to start with a visible password just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
/>
```

and in your code:

```
textInputLayout.getEditText().setTransformationMethod(null);
```

If you want to return to the default behavior:

```
textInputLayout.getEditText()
    .setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just removing `android:inputType="textPassword"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is, we can search `CheckableImageButton` from `TextInputLayout`, and then programmatically perform `onClick` on it, based on the password visibility status of `EditText`.

Here's the code snippet.

```
private CheckableImageButton findCheckableImageButton(View view) {
    if (view instanceof CheckableImageButton) {
        return (CheckableImageButton)view;
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0, ei = viewGroup.getChildCount(); i < ei; i++) {
            CheckableImageButton checkableImageButton = findCheckableImageButton(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
            if (checkableImageButton != null) {
                return checkableImageButton;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

//...

if (passwordEditText.getTransformationMethod() != null) {
    CheckableImageButton checkableImageButton = findCheckableImageButton(passwordTextInputLayout);
    if (checkableImageButton != null) {
        // Make password visible.
        checkableImageButton.performClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to start in clear-text mode with the following bit of code. Basically, I had to find the right View using the content description.

If they provided a setter method for `mPasswordToggledVisibility` that would make things a lot easier...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextInputLayout til = findViewById(R.id.password);
    CharSequence cs = til.getPasswordVisibilityToggleContentDescription();
    ArrayList<View> ov = new ArrayList<>();
    til.findViewsWithText(ov, cs,View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
    if( ov.size() == 1 ) {
        Checkable c = (Checkable)ov.get(0);
        // As far as I can tell the check for "isChecked" here isn't needed,
        // since it always starts unchecked by default. However, if you
        // wanted to check for state, you could do it this way.
        if( c != null && !c.isChecked()) {
            ov.get(0).performClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2019, there's a public method called `passwordVisibilityToggleRequested()` on `TextInputLayout` that does this for you.

Comment: passwordVisibilityToggleRequested is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bellow code:

```
TextInputLayout yourTextInputLayoutId = findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayoutId);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) (yourTextInputLayoutId).getChildAt(0);

CheckableImageButton checkableImageButton = (CheckableImageButton) frameLayout.getChildAt(1);
checkableImageButton.performClick();
```

Here `yourTextInputLayoutId` is your TextInputLayout id from xml.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (inputEditText.getTransformationMethod() == null) {
    inputEditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
} else {
    inputEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);
}


inputEditText.setSelection(inputEditText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with Password visible,
Do not include

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

In

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
.... 

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I just edited the code tags in your post

Comment: Alright, but have you checked and seen if it works?

Comment: I haven't; I'm not faced with this issue, so I can't check the validity of the answers here. Maybe ask the OP and see if what you suggested works in their case and if they benefit from your answer more than they do from the accepted one.

Comment: nice answer pro

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your xml file in TextInputLayout
passwordToggleEnabled="true"
passwordToggleDrawable=""@drawable/show_password_selector"

and make your show_password_selector.xml

this will look the same as the picture you sent

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_visibility_off_24" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_visibility_24"/>
</selector>

Comment: this is show_password_selector.xml

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
yourEditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

To re-show the readable password, just pass null as transformation method:

```
yourEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

so user can hide it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this also makes the toggle button disappear. I have expanded my question to make it clear what is not working.