# how to invert password eye icon?

Tags: android, material-design

[image]

the above eye icon in the edit text showing in reverse order when typing password, the password eye icon is blind when the password is invisible.
 how to invert it

thanks,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
app:passwordToggleTint="#000000">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/password"
android:hint="@string/password"
android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I think that you will have to add a textview and imageview, and manage image in the imageview manually

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must take two `drawable` in and then Change `drawable` image dynamically on button click or any other event like below you may set `drawable` in `EditText` like below:

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, img, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Late Answer.

[Probably, google decided to indicate state button instead of action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password#comment108960691_39022642)

So if you want action button, you can customize icon drawable just using xml layout, no need to change it programmatically.

Add this to TextInputLayout:

```
app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/eye_password"
```

or add this if you use material:1.1.0 or above

```
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/eye_password"
```

then create new drawable for eye_password :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_close" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_open"/>
</selector>
```

drawable for ic_eye_open :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,4.5C7,4.5 2.73,7.61 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5s9.27,-3.11 11,-7.5c-1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5zM12,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3 3,-1.34 3,-3 -1.34,-3 -3,-3z"/>
</vector>
```

drawable for ic_eye_close :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,7c2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 0,0.65 -0.13,1.26 -0.36,1.83l2.92,2.92c1.51,-1.26 2.7,-2.89 3.43,-4.75 -1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5 -1.4,0 -2.74,0.25 -3.98,0.7l2.16,2.16C10.74,7.13 11.35,7 12,7zM2,4.27l2.28,2.28 0.46,0.46C3.08,8.3 1.78,10.02 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5 1.55,0 3.03,-0.3 4.38,-0.84l0.42,0.42L19.73,22 21,20.73 3.27,3 2,4.27zM7.53,9.8l1.55,1.55c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.66 1.34,3 3,3 0.22,0 0.44,-0.03 0.65,-0.08l1.55,1.55c-0.67,0.33 -1.41,0.53 -2.2,0.53 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-0.79 0.2,-1.53 0.53,-2.2zM11.84,9.02l3.15,3.15 0.02,-0.16c0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3l-0.17,0.01z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with version 1.3.0-alpha01. I'm not sure about other versions.

Comment: @fakhruddintahery same thing with 1.2.0 the lastest and stablest version as of 25.08.20 (no alpha or beta)

Comment: I had to update all these values for this solution to work: 

app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/custom_password_eye" 
app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

Answer (score 3):

With the Material Components starting from **`1.2.0-beta01`** it is the default behavior:

[image]
[image]

With the **previous releases** you can do:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_password_eye"
    ..>
```

where `custom_password_eye.xml` is :

```
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="NewApi">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/visible"
        android:drawable="@drawable/design_ic_visibility_off"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/masked"
        android:drawable="@drawable/design_ic_visibility"/>

    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/avd_hide_password"
        android:fromId="@id/masked"
        android:toId="@id/visible"/>

    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/avd_show_password"
        android:fromId="@id/visible"
        android:toId="@id/masked"/>

</animated-selector>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the behavior in version 1.3.0-alpha01. I tried your way but it doesn't work.
Currently, by default, visibility icon is shown when the password is masked and vice versa.

Comment: @fakhruddintahery if you want to invert on 1.3.0-alpha01 you have to invert the drawable in the item and transition.

Comment: the issue is that the icon doesn't get displayed when I use custom_password_eye.xml. in  app:endIconDrawable

Comment: remove `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`  and add `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"`

Answer (score 1):

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout              
           app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/password_toogle"
           app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/inpPassword"
               android:ems="15"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:textColor="#555555"
               android:textSize="14sp" />

       </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---------- password_toogle ---------

```
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_close"
    android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_open"/>
```

You can use property`app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`  simply but it gives inverted icons for hiding and showing passwords