# How to set AppCompatEditText as inputType textPassword programmatically

Tags: android

How can you set `AppCompatEditText` as `inputType textPassword` programatically?

I have tried all possible methods to solve this:

```
pass_et = (AppCompatEditText) loginView.findViewById(R.id.pass_et);
     pass_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            pass_et.setSelection(pass_et.getText().length());
            pass_et.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            pass_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

    pass_et.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            pass_et.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

     pass_et.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf"));       pass_et.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

    pass_et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     pass_et.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            pass_et.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
                    pass_et.setInputType(

                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

                    pass_et.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                }
            });
```

I have also tried:

```
pass_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set inputType for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password

Comment: pass_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD); mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()); all i tried but there is no use, if i add **textPassword** in xml file it is working but font is changing, its different from the font i applied in app

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make changes to your questions to include extra information.

Comment: Your question is wrongly put. Setting input type works but you lose typeface, is that correct? Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `setTransfromationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())`, it's done as part of `setInputType`. Ctrl+click the method name to see source code.

When you set input type to password, typeface is automatically set to monospace. So, set typeface *after* `setInputType`.

And since you already need to call `setTypeface` after everything is set up, you might as well use XML attributes. Then set typeface in code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by this：

```
doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
            setSelection(text?.length ?: 0)
}
```