# Android EditText, toggle password visiblity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

You may say this is duplicated but it's not. Actually I found solutions but none worked perfectly. Last solution was using `TextInputLayout` plus `EditText` inside it but is there a way to move the toggle button to other side of `EditText`? If not, so it's of no use for me.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edlrPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Again, problem is that the toggle button places on the `EditText` making part of it invisible.

I have tried these piece of code too:

```
if (b)
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
else 
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Also I tried this code:

```
 if (b)
     editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
 else
     editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Both work for the first change, and then the text inside `EditText` remains visible all the time.
What should I do? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** So I just noticed I needed to add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to the `TextInputLayout`! Previously I had added it to just `editText`, causing a conflict (as `TextInputLayout` was `ltr` by default) which made toggle button cover the `editText`. By the way when I put my `editText` inside a `TextInputLayout`, then `setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod())` also works perfectly though I don't need it anymore!

Thank all for participation.

Comment: refer  this link  
 https://medium.com/creinno-studio/password-visibility-toggle-android-1571aeeffc05

Answer (score 2):

Add `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` in your `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout`. it will toggle password visibility and vice versa. remove your java code

Comment: Yeah I had done it and it worked. But surprisingly I couldn't find a way to place the visibility toggle button in my desired position. (In my case, left side of my `EditText`)

Comment: @SinbodUser: by default password toggle replaces end drawable, so you won't be able to move it to right, you will need to set drawable left and handle button click manually.

Comment: @SinbodUser if you are using arabic texts then you can change layout direction into rtl

Answer (score 0):

hi you can replace this code and enjoy him !

> edtPassword -> your edit text (Password)
>
> show_password -> imageView For show your password

```
public void setPassword_show() {
    if (!edtPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        if (show_password.getTag().toString().equals(IS_ONE_CLICK)) {
            edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                show_password.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_24dp));
            else
                show_password.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_24dp,
                        null));
            show_password.setTag((Object) IS_TWO_CLICK);
        } else if (show_password.getTag().toString().equals(IS_TWO_CLICK)) {
            edtPassword.setInputType(129);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                show_password.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp));
            else
                show_password.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp, null));
            show_password.setTag((Object) IS_ONE_CLICK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an another way to achieve that kind of 
you need to set drawable left and you need to listen to it's click event through `edittext.setOnTouchListener`
after that follow 
this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685867/10561246