# how to show and hide the word in a password field by clicking on a button

Tags: android

Is it possible to show the word inserted in a password field by clicking on a button and then when I click it again hide the password as dots?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between hide and view password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200sp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showHideBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    showHideBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if(showHideBtn.text.toString().equals("Show")){
            pwd.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            showHideBtn.text = "Hide"
        } else{
            pwd.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            showHideBtn.text = "Show"
        }
    }
}
}
```