# Android SDK: how to solve setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(boolean) is deprecated?

Tags: android, deprecated, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am facing issues with update of android Version.

`setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(boolean)' is deprecated`

I want my login view ***to switch between hide and show password toggle icon in TextInputLayout***.

But, how do I use instead of using `setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(boolean)`?

I also searched this on Google and I found **they recommend me to use `setEndIconDrawable(int)` instead.**

But I don't know how to use it?

I also found this [How to switch between hide and view password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password) But I don't wanna use this code.

Is there any other way to develop like this? 
Thank you all!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instead use:

```java
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE)
```

[Docs for `setEndIconMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setendiconmode)

[Docs for `END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#end_icon_password_toggle)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#getEndIconMode() Here you can see the information about the new method for hiding / showing text