# implement uitextfield properties in android

Tags: android

I am an android and iphone developer. I am a newbie though working on this huge project. I am trying to implement the leftView, leftviewmode,rightview,rightviewmode properties of the textfield in iphone in android.

I was thinking that with the leftview and rightview the setCompoundDrawables() method could meet the challenge. However, I am stumped as to how to implement the various modes; "Never", "always" etc.

Am I on the right track? Could anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will give you an Android EditText field that functions exactly like an iPhone UITextField with options for clearbuttonmode, leftview, rightview, leftviewmode, rightviewmode, UITextFieldViewModeNever, UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing, UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing, UITextFieldViewModeAlways

```
    String value = "";//any text you are pre-filling in the EditText
    final String viewMode = "editing";//never | editing | unlessEditing | always
    final String viewSide = "right"; //left | right
    final EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText(value);
    //your leftview, rightview or clearbuttonmode image. for clearbuttonmode this one from standard android images looks pretty good actually
    final Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.presence_offline);
    x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
    Drawable x2 = viewMode.equals("never")?null:viewMode.equals("always")?x:viewMode.equals("editing")?(value.equals("") ? null : x):viewMode.equals("unlessEditing")?(value.equals("") ? x : null):null;
    et.setCompoundDrawables(viewSide.equals("left")?x2:null, null, viewSide.equals("right")?x2:null, null);
    et.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (et.getCompoundDrawables()[viewSide.equals("left")?0:2] == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return false;
            }
            //x pressed
            if ((viewSide.equals("left")&&event.getX() < et.getPaddingLeft() + x.getIntrinsicWidth())
                    ||(viewSide.equals("right")&&event.getX() > et.getWidth() - et.getPaddingRight() - x.getIntrinsicWidth())) {
                Drawable x3 = viewMode.equals("never")?null:viewMode.equals("always")?x:viewMode.equals("editing")?null:viewMode.equals("unlessEditing")?x:null;
                et.setText("");
                et.setCompoundDrawables(viewSide.equals("left")?x3:null, null, viewSide.equals("right")?x3:null, null);
            }          
            return false;
        }
    });
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Drawable x4 = viewMode.equals("never")?null:viewMode.equals("always")?x:viewMode.equals("editing")?(et.getText().toString().equals("") ? null : x):viewMode.equals("unlessEditing")?(et.getText().toString().equals("") ? x : null):null;
           et.setCompoundDrawables(viewSide.equals("left")?x4:null, null, viewSide.equals("right")?x4:null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
    });
```