# How to create EditText with cross(x) button at end of it?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any widget like `EditText` which contains a cross button, or is there any property for `EditText` by which it is created automatically? I want the cross button to delete whatever text written in `EditText`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be any standard widget for it.  But you find a few different approaches with a Google search for "android edittext clear button x".  So I guess "clear buttons" is what they call it.  Also, see this answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175398/clear-edittext-on-click/6235602#6235602

Comment: You can download source here: https://github.com/GhOsTTT/editTextXbutton have a nice day

Comment: another question that is essentially a duplicate is *[implement uitextfield properties in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274021/implement-uitextfield-properties-in-android/)*

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calc_txt_Prise"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"  
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="@string/calc_txt_Prise"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc_clear_txt_Prise"      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/delete" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can also use the button's id and perform whatever action you want on its onClickListener method.

Comment: this is a inefficient way of doing it. yanchenko's answer is right approach of using compound drawables.

Comment: If you happen to choose this solution and notice that the image is stretched a lot too much, you should probably use an ImageButton instead of a regular Button.

Comment: While this solution is "inefficient", it's a lot more accessible for blind users. Using a drawable will force your users to perform very complicated operations to clearing the text - something that seeing users can do quickly with the X button.

Comment: What's the inefficiency about this?

Answer (score 179):

2020 solution via Material Design Components for Android:

Add Material Components to your gradle setup:

*Look for latest version from here: https://maven.google.com/*

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

or if you havent updated to using AndroidX libs, you can add it this way:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Then

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Pay attention to: **app:endIconMode="clear_text"**

As discussed here [Material design docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer.  In my case, I wasn't able to implement without updating to AndroidX libraries.

Comment: @Ben (thumbs up)

Comment: Please be sure to read through documentation as not all of the xml attributes are supported yet. You may have to look through the source or commit messages as those are sometimes where exact implementation details are. I had this type of issue for a custom endIcon. A commit message revealed that the xml attribute had no implementation backing it yet. Will have to use a different approach until implementation is finished

Comment: Best answer in 2020.

Comment: does app:endIconMode="clear_text" is workign with `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText/>` ? can you please help me in same

Comment: @Arbaz.in Not sure to be honest, just make sure you're wrapping your EditText with "TextInputLayout", if it didnt work, then you need to replace your "AppCompatEditText" with "TextInputEditText".

Comment: can i have 2 endiconmode?

Comment: @kevoroid when i use implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' some errors comming up, i used its latest version also but all of them causing some AAPT2 errors.What to do??

Comment: Why is this input box so thick (almost twice as tall as regular EditText)?

Comment: I'm using Material 1.5.0 and the icon doesn't show up

Comment: Don't forget to set the tint of the icon! ;)

Answer (score 121):

If you happen to use *DroidParts*, I've just added [ClearableEditText](https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts-misc/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java).

Here's what it looks like with a custom background & clear icon set to `abs__ic_clear_holo_light` from *ActionBarSherlock*:

[image]

Comment: Best solution because the class extends `EditText`. Thx @yanchenko

Comment: This is good, but when I tap on the icon, it clears the text but also shows the "paste" button, how strange is that?

Comment: @stephanek. I've fixed this in the develop branch, will be part of the 1.4.3 release.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use this solution and also call [TextView.setError(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)) you will have to reset the right drawable after clearing the error text.

Comment: Thanks! It would be really cool though if you could also include a ClearableAutoCompleteTextView in DroidParts. For others users that also try to do this: use DroidParts library, copy the code from ClearableEditText and just extend AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: This is bomb! You can also use it standalone changing the TextWatcherAdapter dependency with a normal TextWatcher.

Comment: @yanchenko Hey, I've just been using your clearableEditText and found some abnormal response to touch events. If you start by pressing the x then moving your finger to the right, outside of the edit text, the field would clear. To resolve this I changed a bit of code in your on touch method so that it only clears touches that start and end within the bounds of the X.

Comment: @yanchenko             
boolean tappedX = event.getX() > (getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - xD.getIntrinsicWidth())

&& event.getX() < getWidth()

&& event.getY() > 0 // The x any y pos start in the bottom left of the view.

&& event.getY() < getHeight(); // So between 0 and height(of the edit text) is the bounds of the view.

Comment: @yanchenko Had a look at your implementation. Seems like there is a bit of a trade off between the accepted touch area being rather small and having an edit text with a larger than default height accepting touch events all along the y axis within the edit text. Your implementation was the former and mine the latter. In similar circumstances would you recommend doing the same? i.e. go for a smaller hit box that could be miss-pressed or have a larger hit box, where, with an expanding or larger edit text the presses could be well outside the bounds of the drawable.

Comment: I have  a xamarin solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069323/clearableedittext-for-xamarin-android/49494031#49494031

Comment: Including the latest version (3.2.5) of `droidparts` works, but using the `ClearableEditText` like in the example code does not work for me.

Comment: @yanchenko I have a datepicker edittext field where android:focusable="false" , how can i use this for such fields???pls help

Comment: How to install with Gradle: `implementation 'org.droidparts:droidparts-misc:3.2.5'`

Answer (score 38):

This is a kotlin solution. Put this helper method in some kotlin file-

```
fun EditText.setupClearButtonWithAction() {

    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            val clearIcon = if (editable?.isNotEmpty() == true) R.drawable.ic_clear else 0
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, clearIcon, 0)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) = Unit
    })

    setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.rawX >= (this.right - this.compoundPaddingRight)) {
                this.setText("")
                return@OnTouchListener true
            }
        }
        return@OnTouchListener false
    })
}
```

And then use it as following in the `onCreate` method and you should be good to go-

```
yourEditText.setupClearButtonWithAction()
```

BTW, you have to add `R.drawable.ic_clear` or the clear icon at first. This one is from google- https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Aclear%3A

Comment: If you insert `this.clearFocus()` before the return true statement, you can listen to this event on the EditText caller with the `onFocusChange` listener

Comment: Great it's wotking ,
only issue is i set drawable left icon in AppCompatEditText and it'll remove when i call this funcion can you please tell me what the issue?

Comment: @Arbaz.in It is because of calling method `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, clearIcon, 0)` . You can pass the left drawable icon id as a new param to this function and put it in the call.

Comment: @Gulshan i have done same still remove that drawable

Answer (score 24):

Android's support libarary has a [`SearchView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html) class that does exactly this.  (Not derrived from `EditText` though, so have to use a [`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) instead of a `TextWatcher`)

[image: Search view with no text (and hint text "Search")]

[image]

Use in XML like so:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="@string/SearchHint"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="@string/SearchHint" />
```

Answer (score 15):

```
Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.x);
x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
mEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, x, null);
```

where, x is:

[image]

Comment: Still we need to assign an onClickListener right? A quick search gave me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext). 
Guess better solution is to go with the Framelayout one. Thanks though!

Answer (score 13):

For `drawable resource` you can use standard android images :

[web archive for http://androiddrawables.com/Menu.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171127224252/http://www.androiddrawables.com/Menu.html)

For example :

```
android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
```

Comment: FWIW, the linked domain is dead and has been domain-squatted. This is the last update of what it looked like, showing 4.1-7.1. Very nice :) https://web.archive.org/web/20171127224252/http://www.androiddrawables.com/Menu.html

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use custom views or special layouts, you can use 9-patch to make the (X) button .

Example: http://postimg.org/image/tssjmt97p/ (I don't have enough points to post images on StackOverflow)

The intersection of the right and bottom black pixels represent the content area. Anything outside of that area is padding. So to detect that the user clicked on the x you can set a OnTouchListener like so:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (motionEvent.getX()>(view.getWidth()-view.getPaddingRight())){
                ((EditText)view).setText("");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

According to your needs this solution can work better in some cases. I prefer to keep my xml less complicated. This also helps if you want to have an icon on the left, as you can simply include it in the 9 patch.

Comment: Use `motionEvent.getRawX()`.

Comment: @CoolMind Wouldn't `motionEvent.getRawX()` return absolute coordinates (relative to the screen)? This solution needs the coordinates to be relative to the view, which `motionEvent.getX()` does.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but in my case `getRawX()` helped. Also two solutions on this page use `rawX()`. But I agree with you, it depends on situation.

Answer (score 7):

Just put close cross like `drawableEnd` in your `EditText`:

```
<EditText
     ...
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_close"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
     ... />
```

and use extension **to handle click** (or use `OnTouchListener` directly on your `EditText`):

```
fun EditText.onDrawableEndClick(action: () -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v as EditText
            val end = if (v.resources.configuration.layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
                v.left else v.right
            if (event.rawX >= (end - v.compoundPaddingEnd)) {
                action.invoke()
                return@setOnTouchListener true
            }
        }
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}
```

*extension usage:*

```
editText.onDrawableEndClick {
    // TODO clear action
    etSearch.setText("")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Clear text:

> "Text field with a clear text trailing icon."

If set, an icon is displayed when text is present and pressing it clears the input text.

```
    ...
    app:endIconMode="clear_text">
​
    ...
​
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I leave it here:

[material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields)

Example

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks! You save my day! This works fine for API 24+

Comment: Exactly done it this way. Not working. Icon doens't show up

Answer (score 4):

Here is complete library with the widget:
https://github.com/opprime/EditTextField

To use it you should add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.optimus:editTextField:0.2.0'
```

In the layout.xml file you can play with the widget settings:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

- app:clearButtonMode，can has such values:
  never
  always
  whileEditing
  unlessEditing
- app:clearButtonDrawable

Sample in action:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did the UI part like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearchToolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivClearSearchText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**edittext_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_focused.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#C9C9CE" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

*balloon_overlay_close.png*[image]

**Cross/Clear button hide/show:**

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(charSequence.length() > 0){
            clearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            clearSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
```

**Handle search stuffs (i.e when user clicks search from soft key board)**

```
searchBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            String contents = searchBox.getText().toString().trim();
            if(contents.length() > 0){
                //do search

            }else{
                //if something to do for empty edittext
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Clear/Cross button**

```
clearSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        searchBox.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet with Jaydip answer for more than one button. just call it after getting a reference to the ET and Button Elements. I used vecotr button so you have to change the Button element to ImageButton:

```
private void setRemovableET(final EditText et, final ImageButton resetIB) {

        et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus && et.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    resetIB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    resetIB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        resetIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et.setText("");
                resetIB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() != 0){
                    resetIB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    resetIB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in frame layout  or you can create a frame layout I tried another approach....

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_actionbar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_button"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear_text_invisible_button"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    />
```

This is an edit text where I put a cross icon as a right drawable and than UPON it I put a transparent button which clears text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/idSearchEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
    android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
/>

EditText mSearchEditText = findViewById(R.id.idSearchEditText);
mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
mSearchEditText.setOnTouchListener(this);


@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable aEditable) {
    int clearIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all;
    int searchIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search;
    if (aEditable == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(aEditable.toString())) {
        clearIcon = 0;
        searchIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search;
    } else {
        clearIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all;
        searchIcon = 0;
    }
    Drawable leftDrawable =  null;
    if (searchIcon != 0) {
        leftDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(searchIcon);
    }
    Drawable rightDrawable = null;
    if (clearIcon != 0) {
        rightDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(clearIcon);
    }

    mSearchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(leftDrawable, null, rightDrawable, null);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View aView, MotionEvent aEvent) {
    if (aEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (aEvent.getX() > ( mSearchEditText.getWidth() - 
         mSearchEditText.getCompoundPaddingEnd())){
            mSearchEditText.setText("");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple complete solution in kotlin.

This whole layout will be your search bar

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/your_desired_drawable">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/clear_btn"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="search..."
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_clear_24"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now this is the functionality of clear button, paste this code in onCreate method.

```
search_et.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int, after:Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int) {
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (s.isNotEmpty()){
                    clear_btn.visibility = VISIBLE
                    clear_btn.setOnClickListener {
                        search_et.text.clear()
                    }
                }else{
                    clear_btn.visibility = GONE
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a best way to create custom clearable edittext with close icon and gettextcleanlistener

```
class EditTextWithClear : AppCompatEditText {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attributeSet,
    defStyleAttr
)

private val blackClearDrawable =
    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_clear_text, null) as Drawable
private val opaqueClearDrawable =
    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_clear_text, null) as Drawable

private var clearButtonImage: Drawable = opaqueClearDrawable
private var onTextClearListener: OnTextClearListener? = null

fun setOnTextClearListener(onTextClearListener: OnTextClearListener) {
    this.onTextClearListener = onTextClearListener
}

private fun showClearButton() {
    setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, clearButtonImage, null)
}

private fun hideClearButton() {
    setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (isClearButtonVisible() && wasClearButtonTouched(event)) {
        onClearButtonTouched(event)
        return true
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}

override fun onTextChanged(
    text: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    lengthBefore: Int,
    lengthAfter: Int
) {
    if (text?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        showClearButton()
    } else {
        onTextClearListener?.onTextClearListener()
        hideClearButton()
    }
}

private fun isClearButtonVisible(): Boolean {
    return compoundDrawablesRelative[2] != null
}

private fun wasClearButtonTouched(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val isClearButtonAtTheStart = layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL

    return if (isClearButtonAtTheStart) {

        val clearButtonEnd = paddingStart + clearButtonImage.intrinsicWidth
        event.x < clearButtonEnd

    } else {

        val clearButtonStart = width - clearButtonImage.intrinsicWidth - paddingEnd
        event.x > clearButtonStart

    }
}

private fun onClearButtonTouched(event: MotionEvent) {
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            clearButtonImage = blackClearDrawable
            showClearButton()
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            clearButtonImage = opaqueClearDrawable
            text?.clear()
            hideClearButton()
        }
    }
}

interface OnTextClearListener {
    fun onTextClearListener()
}

/*
This code use your activity and fragment
editext.setOnTextClearListener(object : EditTextWithClear.OnTextClearListener{
    override fun onTextClearListener() {
        //perform action when empty your edittext
    }
})*/}
```

Xml code

```
<com.example.clearbaleedittext.utility.EditTextWithClear
    android:id="@+id/etEditext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_normal"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dp_12"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dp_12"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16"
    />
```