# Does Android EditText has input type with clear button?

Tags: android

Does Android EditText has input type with clear button?

It should work like html 5 search input type.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create EditText with cross(x) button at end of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355096/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no internal input-type, but you can customize it to work so. This link might help you: [Stack-Overflow: EditText with clear button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355096/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it)

Comment: Sad, I hope android will handle it for me

Comment: don't be sad, use app:endIconMode="clear_text" in TextInputLayout.

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi Does android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout has this function, if not pls specify which TextInputLayout to use??

Comment: see @sergio-sánchez-sánchez answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64786871/5853262

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following, it works quite well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    tools:hint="Label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Value" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

But this approach would not be valid for a MaterialAutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `TextInputLayout` that you can use `endIconMode` and `endIconDrawable`

Comment: Does android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout has this function, if not pls specify which TextInputLayout to use??

Comment: @KJEjava48 use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`.
And icon you can set from `.xml`. Like, `app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/xxx`.

Comment: I have a datepicker edittext field where android:focusable="false" , how can i use this for such fields???pls help

Comment: Has this field been renamed to `drawableEnd` now?