# Button with more touchable area

Tags: android, button, touch

> Implemented clear button for EditText according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355178/2255924). The
>   button is really small and it is very hard to get touched. How to make
>   button's touchable area bigger?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use a touch delegate

[Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html)

2)  or put the button in a separate LinearLayout which wraps the content with the appropriate padding according to the size of the clickable area you want and set it clickable with the button inside as parameter.

Comment: I found tutorial about touch delegate:http://www.daggie.be/?p=1006 It has line of code:bounds.right += 100; I understood this make touch area to the right. But I don't understant what is 100? Is it dp, sp, px? Do you reccomend doing it in this way

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use an ImageButton where You set the image that You want to show as a button to "centerInside" and then use padding. For example:

```
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/your_image_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/your_selector" 
        android:padding="30dp"/>
```

if You set the background to transparent and us padding values, the picture will be smaller, but the buttons size will stay. This is just an example to show You what I mean, think about to set the right width/height values. Play with padding values until You reach what You want. The Image is a part of Your selector, that You have to set as src.

Answer (score 0):

using padding attribute. "wrap_content" will be as big as its content plus padding.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calc_clear_txt_Prise"      
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/delete" />
```

The button will expand until it wraps both content and the padding.

Also, show us your code and we could help more accurately.

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_padding' in package 'android'