# Android To remove selected contact from Edit-Text View

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contacts

For my application i am providing a Single Edit-Text View along with a "Pick Contact" Button. When user clicks the pick contact button, it will open the phone-book where he can select a contact. What i want is when a contact get displayed in the edit-text view, a small cross will get appear on the edit-text view, click on that, will remove the contact from edit-text.What to do, in this case.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355096/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it

Comment: the person has added button a button, but in my application. i am allowing user to add mutliple edit-text views :(

Comment: ok i mean the second post where the user post a link (https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/develop/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java) and instead of the default edittext you can create the edittext from the link. But i think in your case a custome textview is better, because with the edittext solution you clear the edittext but it is still presented. if you take a custome edittext like with border and an cross on the top right, the user press this and you can remove this textview