# Change an text of an edittext when it is clicked

Tags: android

I'm trying to clear the contents of an edittext box when it is clicked.  Currently my code is as follows:

```
EditText TextOut1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search);
TextOut1.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

This code will change the edittext box when bound to a button, but not when bound to an edit textbox.

Comment: Figured out that adding android:hint in the layout got what i was looking for "more or less"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear an EditText on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175398/how-to-clear-an-edittext-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

**1)Set the listener on your `EditText` :**

```
textOut1.setOnFocusChangeListener (this);
```

**2)Let your `Activity` implements the `View.OnFocusChangeListener` :**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{
```

**3)override the method `onFocusChange` :**

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){

    if(hasFocus){
       EditText TextOut1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search);
       TextOut1.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }

}
```