# drawableRight of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Below is my layout:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/account_et"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_backall"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/str_md_email"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>
```

I want to show the drawableRight when EditText be focused.
And hide while without focus.
Another one is that I want to set OnClickListener of drawableRight.
How can I do?

Comment: This might solve one of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my sample will help you

```
activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ImageView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the class file in which drawable options are performed

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.doubtedittext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etext;
    private ImageView imageView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        etext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (hasFocus) {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity
                                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

the operation you required successfully performed above.....

Comment: Wrong answer, this not for DrawableRight

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest you to add imageView  separated from the EditText and align him to be on top of him with align top and align right and that you have full control so you can invisible him and setOnClickListner

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/account_et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/account_et"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/account_et"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_backall">
    </ImageView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [View.OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html). Putting drawable to edittext when you catch the focus, then replacing drawable with null would solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. But how to add OnClickListener of drawableRight?

Comment: Actually to achive this, you got to create 1 ViewGroup and 2 View (EditText and ImageView). Your OnFocusChangeListener will be attached to edittext and your on click listener will be attached to image view. Frame layout would do the trick here as ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Use like belwo

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           if(hasFocus)
                           {}
else {}


            }
        });
```