# Ui effect for a textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Please watch the customer name and country and arrow in the list view ,i would like to implement the same effect for text view in my application .]

Please watch the customer name and country and arrow in the list view ,i would like to implement the same effect for text view in my application.
i.e the text should place at left side and right side arrow mark and if we touches the textview it should display some other screen.

Comment: [Segmented Radio Buttons for Android](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton)

Comment: TextView support Drawable right,Top,Left,Bottom property you can bind event on it please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753816/drawableright-of-edittext

Comment: @Andil atleat give some related answer.

Answer (score 0):

That would not be a single TextView but rather one list item RelativeLayout or LinearLayout with two TextViews inside of it and an ImageView for the arrow graphic on the right. It would be with a ListActivity or ListFragment which would handle the touching for you, taking you to another screen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

As shown on the site, your code would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/country"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Then just tweak it accordingly.

EDIT---

Once you have your view in XML, then you can add a click listener like this in your Activity:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do your code here to switch to another view or activity
    }
});
```

Comment: i have only one text view and image view so i am placing them in a linear layout .trying to make touch effect for the layout.

Comment: Are you using a ListView or ListFragment? That's what you would want if you're trying to achieve what the picture has that you posted.

Comment: In the image if we touch any where on the list item i.e contact name ,country ,arrow it redirects to some other screen ,i would like to implement the same effect.

Comment: but i have only one item so not interested in using list view or list fragment is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer. Add a click listener to your LinearLayout; that should do it!