# Setting onClickListener for the Drawable right of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app I have a `EditText` with a search Icon on the right side. I used the code given below.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_search1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:hint="Search Anything..."
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

I want to set the `onClickListener` for the search icon image assigned to the right drawable 
of `EditText`. How is it possible?

Comment: dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext

Comment: Simplest solution using Android provided API http://stackoverflow.com/a/26269435/185022 :-)

Comment: This is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37032927/346309

Comment: If you are using `TextInputLayout` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940540/9723204. It's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
public class CustomEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private Drawable drawableRight;
    private Drawable drawableLeft;
    private Drawable drawableTop;
    private Drawable drawableBottom;

    int actionX, actionY;

    private DrawableClickListener clickListener;

    public CustomEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // this Contructure required when you are using this view in xml
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);        
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
            Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        if (left != null) {
            drawableLeft = left;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            drawableRight = right;
        }
        if (top != null) {
            drawableTop = top;
        }
        if (bottom != null) {
            drawableBottom = bottom;
        }
        super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Rect bounds;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            actionX = (int) event.getX();
            actionY = (int) event.getY();
            if (drawableBottom != null
                    && drawableBottom.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.BOTTOM);
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            if (drawableTop != null
                    && drawableTop.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawablePosition.TOP);
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            // this works for left since container shares 0,0 origin with bounds
            if (drawableLeft != null) {
                bounds = null;
                bounds = drawableLeft.getBounds();

                int x, y;
                int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density  + 0.5);

                x = actionX;
                y = actionY;

                if (!bounds.contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                    /** Gives the +20 area for tapping. */
                    x = (int) (actionX - extraTapArea);
                    y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);

                    if (x <= 0)
                        x = actionX;
                    if (y <= 0)
                        y = actionY;

                    /** Creates square from the smallest value */
                    if (x < y) {
                        y = x;
                    }
                }

                if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener
                            .onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.LEFT);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    return false;

                }
            }

            if (drawableRight != null) {

                bounds = null;
                bounds = drawableRight.getBounds();

                int x, y;
                int extraTapArea = 13;

                /**
                 * IF USER CLICKS JUST OUT SIDE THE RECTANGLE OF THE DRAWABLE
                 * THAN ADD X AND SUBTRACT THE Y WITH SOME VALUE SO THAT AFTER
                 * CALCULATING X AND Y CO-ORDINATE LIES INTO THE DRAWBABLE
                 * BOUND. - this process help to increase the tappable area of
                 * the rectangle.
                 */
                x = (int) (actionX + extraTapArea);
                y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);

                /**Since this is right drawable subtract the value of x from the width 
                * of view. so that width - tappedarea will result in x co-ordinate in drawable bound. 
                */
                x = getWidth() - x;
                
                 /*x can be negative if user taps at x co-ordinate just near the width.
                 * e.g views width = 300 and user taps 290. Then as per previous calculation
                 * 290 + 13 = 303. So subtract X from getWidth() will result in negative value.
                 * So to avoid this add the value previous added when x goes negative.
                 */
                 
                if(x <= 0){
                    x += extraTapArea;
                }
                
                 /* If result after calculating for extra tappable area is negative.
                 * assign the original value so that after subtracting
                 * extratapping area value doesn't go into negative value.
                 */               
                 
                if (y <= 0)
                    y = actionY;                

                /**If drawble bounds contains the x and y points then move ahead.*/
                if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener
                            .onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    return false;
                }
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }           

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        drawableRight = null;
        drawableBottom = null;
        drawableLeft = null;
        drawableTop = null;
        super.finalize();
    }

    public void setDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener listener) {
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Also Create an Interface with

```
public interface DrawableClickListener {

    public static enum DrawablePosition { TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT };
    public void onClick(DrawablePosition target); 
    }
```

Still if u need any help, comment

Also set the drawableClickListener on the view in activity file.

```
editText.setDrawableClickListener(new DrawableClickListener() {
        
         
        public void onClick(DrawablePosition target) {
            switch (target) {
            case LEFT:
                //Do something here
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: I would have also passed the Edittext as the parameter to the callback. But a good answer never the less.

Comment: I created the custom EditText. If i touch anywhere in the its going to   the onTouchMovement method. but never goes to here "if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener
                            .onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    return false;
                }"

Comment: Hi, I am not find CoreSystemContext.SCALE , so code shows Error. how I can get CoreSystemContext.SCALE. Please advise.

Comment: That is the variable holding device density. use getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density instead of that, you might need to create a static varaible in some other file. This to convert px to dp. A simple solution would be to remove that variable.

Comment: Please add the statement `playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);` after `if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {` in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method so that user can get a click sound.

Comment: If you cant find  CoreSystemContext.SCALE, just Change this line            int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5);

Comment: Too much code. A simple setOnTouchListener will work with this.

Comment: @V-J can  you  comment a sample working code :D

Answer (score 43):

This has been already answered but I tried a different way to make it simpler.

The idea is using putting an `ImageButton` on the right of `EditText` and having negative margin to it so that the `EditText` flows into the `ImageButton` making it look like the Button is in the `EditText`.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Pin"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pastePin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also, as shown above, you can use a `paddingRight` of similar width in the `EditText` if you don't want the text in it to be flown over the `ImageButton`.

I guessed margin size with the help of android-studio's layout designer and it looks similar across all screen sizes. Or else you can calculate the width of the `ImageButton` and set the margin programatically.

Comment: It's the simple stuff that works best.

Comment: this is redundant work for single drawable

Comment: margin and padding issues will be there for variety of devices

Comment: Linter will give you a warning "inefficient layout tree, use compound drawable", also more code than drawableRight=""...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts

Comment: why not use simple FrameLayout ?

Comment: `having negative margin to it` That! There goes a hack into it. I would always implement a cleaner solution. The hack is bound to bite you some time later in future.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have access to the right image as far my knowledge, unless you override the `onTouch` event. I suggest to use a `RelativeLayout`, with one `editText` and one `imageView`, and set `OnClickListener` over the image view as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSearch"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:ems="10"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btnsearch" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I recently had to do something very similar, and came up with a much simpler solution.

It boils down to the following steps:

1. Create an XML layout that contains the EditText and Image
2. Subclass FrameLayout and inflate the XML layout
3. Add code for the click listener and any other behavior you want... without having to worry about positions of the click or any other messy code.

See this post for the full example:
[Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext/22945875#22945875)

Answer (score -2):

Please use below trick:

- Create an image button with your icon and set its background color to be transparent.
- Put the image button on the EditText
- Implement the 'onclic'k listener of the button to execute your function

Comment: what if the size of the editText increase ?, what if I have many editText which requires this, which usually happens.

Comment: You need to understand the question! He/she isn't asking an alternative solution.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that falls apart as soon as you start changing the text size on the EditText. You might think that's just on the developer's side but it's not as far as the devices have text size in settings.You can avoid this using dp instead of sp on the EditText but it just makes things worse. The other problems are things like handling multiline EditTexts