# Click event for the Drawable Left of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

I am following [Setting onClickListner for the Drawable right of an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext/13135554#13135554) for my purpose,

But I am not getting CoreSystemContext.SCALE in code. So it shows Error. How I can get CoreSystemContext.SCALE.

Comment: i am getting same error ....