# Where i will get this CoreSystemContext.SCALE in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

See bellow Image

[image: See bellow Image]

[Check this link But I din't get CoreSystemContext.SCALE . now i am getting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext)

Please Help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original author of this code replied to this question in the comments:

> That is the variable holding the device density.

So just use this:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * density  + 0.5);
```

Comment: Yes I have solved this problem. Thanks