# Programatically creating Custom EditText with Drawable

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a CustomeEditText using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135554/4294399) in my android application for assigning a drawable click on the right Drawable.

The class is given below.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    private Drawable drawableRight;
    private Drawable drawableLeft;
    private Drawable drawableTop;
    private Drawable drawableBottom;

    int actionX, actionY;
    int mHeight = 0;

    private DrawableClickListener clickListener;

        public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // this Contructure required when you are using this view in xml
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mHeight = h;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
            Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        Log.v("Login", "setCompoundDrawables");
        if (left != null) {
            Log.v("Login", "Left Not Null");
            drawableLeft = left;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            drawableRight = right;
        }
        if (top != null) {
            drawableTop = top;
        }
        if (bottom != null) {
            drawableBottom = bottom;
        }
        Log.v("CustomeEditText", "Left :"+left);
        
        super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Rect bounds;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            actionX = (int) event.getX();
            actionY = (int) event.getY();
            if (drawableBottom != null
                    && drawableBottom.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.BOTTOM);
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            if (drawableTop != null
                    && drawableTop.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.TOP);
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            // this works for left since container shares 0,0 origin with bounds
            if (drawableLeft != null) {
                bounds = null;
                bounds = drawableLeft.getBounds();

                int x, y;
                int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5);

                x = actionX;
                y = actionY;

                if (!bounds.contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                    /** Gives the +20 area for tapping. */
                    x = (int) (actionX - extraTapArea);
                    y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);

                    if (x <= 0)
                        x = actionX;
                    if (y <= 0)
                        y = actionY;

                    /** Creates square from the smallest value */
                    if (x < y) {
                        y = x;
                    }
                }

                if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener
                            .onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.LEFT);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    return false;

                }
            }

            if (drawableRight != null) {

                bounds = null;
                bounds = drawableRight.getBounds();

                int x, y;
                int extraTapArea = 13;

                /**
                 * IF USER CLICKS JUST OUT SIDE THE RECTANGLE OF THE DRAWABLE
                 * THAN ADD X AND SUBTRACT THE Y WITH SOME VALUE SO THAT AFTER
                 * CALCULATING X AND Y CO-ORDINATE LIES INTO THE DRAWBABLE
                 * BOUND. - this process help to increase the tappable area of
                 * the rectangle.
                 */
                x = (int) (actionX + extraTapArea);
                y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);

                /**
                 * Since this is right drawable subtract the value of x from the
                 * width of view. so that width - tappedarea will result in x
                 * co-ordinate in drawable bound.
                 */
                x = getWidth() - x;

                /*
                 * x can be negative if user taps at x co-ordinate just near the
                 * width. e.g views width = 300 and user taps 290. Then as per
                 * previous calculation 290 + 13 = 303. So subtract X from
                 * getWidth() will result in negative value. So to avoid this
                 * add the value previous added when x goes negative.
                 */

                if (x <= 0) {
                    x += extraTapArea;
                }

                /*
                 * If result after calculating for extra tappable area is
                 * negative. assign the original value so that after subtracting
                 * extratapping area value doesn't go into negative value.
                 */

                if (y <= 0)
                    y = actionY;

                /**
                 * If drawble bounds contains the x and y points then move
                 * ahead.
                 */
                if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener
                            .onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    return false;
                }
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        drawableRight = null;
        drawableBottom = null;
        drawableLeft = null;
        drawableTop = null;
        super.finalize();
    }

    public void setDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener listener) {
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface DrawableClickListener {

        public static enum DrawablePosition {
            TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT
        };

        public void onClick(DrawablePosition target);
    }

}
```

So in the xml

```
<com.mypack.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/category"
        android:hint="My hint"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Now i want to create the same view through code.

I tried to create like this

```
CustomEditText example = new CustomEditText(this);
    Log.v("Login", "message");
    example.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_category), null, null, null);
    example.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_background);
    example.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    example.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
            android.R.color.white));
    //example.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4);
    example.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    example.setTextSize(20);
    example.setText(category);
    ll.addView(example);
```

It is creating a normal edittext without drawable on left side.How i can create a CustomeEditText with Drawable on Right Side.

Comment: I wonder `CustomEditText example = new CustomEditText(this);` code. In you `EditText` class does not have constructor with one parameter

Comment: I added a Constructor public CustomEditText(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }
on CustomeEditText. I added now in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
example.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_category), null, null, null);
```

Instead of

```
example.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_category), null, null, null);
```

This will result in the your custom `EditText` with `Drawable` on left side.

So your code will be like :

```
CustomEditText example = new CustomEditText(this);
    Log.v("Login", "message");
    example.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_category), null, null, null);
    example.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_background);
    example.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    example.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
            android.R.color.white));
    //example.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4);
    example.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    example.setTextSize(20);
    example.setText(category);
    ll.addView(example);
```

**1. setCompoundDrawable to add Drawables:**

If you want to use `setCompoundDrawable` to add `Drawables` then you need to specify the bounds using setBounds. That will define a bounding rectangle around the image. If you don't do that, you wont be able to see the `Drawable`.

eg. In your case use it like,

```
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_category);
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
example.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

**2. setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds to add Drawables:**

You can use `setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds()` instead. It will use the size of the image as the size of the `Drawable`. ie The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

Answer (score -1):

android:gravity="right"

put it in your xml or setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: I am able to create a Custom EditText through an xml file. I want the same by code. how this SetGravity will help me on that ? :-(