# Android: How to make textview as well as a rightDrawable icon clickable separately

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application, I have some `Textview` which `onClick` show some statistics but I've an icon on that `Textview` also, I need to make that icons clickable also that shows some other statistics, Is there any way to do that so that one `Textview` has two `onClickListeners()` which behaves separately, like the image below text is clickable with `textview.setOnClickListener()` but need to make icon clickable also with other functionality.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use Textview and Button in relative layout

Comment: Use TextView and button and align button leftOf textview and you can't change view then look at this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3581464/646806)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to move the drawable to a separate `ImageView` if it needds to do something else when clicked than the TextView.

Comment: no need op can use a compound textview and place th drawable to the right of text

Comment: is there any way to make multiple clickable zones on textview

Comment: i don't want to make drawable separate from textview due to some reasons

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to achieve it. You have to set `setOnTouchListener` on the TextView and

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the textview and an Imageview in a horizonal LinearLayout. You can specify a background to it so that it looks as one single field.
Using onClick method of each view you can display whichever statistics you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement two click listeners for your textview as well as drawble item then you can go for custom view. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135554/1265724) for implementing clicklistener for drawable Item.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

**CustomEditText.java**

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText
{
  private Drawable dRight;
  private Rect rBounds;

  public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }
  public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }
  public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
      Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
  {
    if(right !=null)
    {
      dRight = right;
    }
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
  {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && dRight!=null)
    {
      rBounds = dRight.getBounds();
      final int x = (int)event.getX();
      final int y = (int)event.getY();
      //System.out.println("x:/y: "+x+"/"+y);
      //System.out.println("bounds: "+bounds.left+"/"+bounds.right+"/"+bounds.top+"/"+bounds.bottom);
      //check to make sure the touch event was within the bounds of the drawable
      if(x>=(this.getRight()-rBounds.width()) && x<=(this.getRight()-this.getPaddingRight())
          && y>=this.getPaddingTop() && y<=(this.getHeight()-this.getPaddingBottom()))
      {
        //System.out.println("touch");
        this.setText("");
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);//use this to prevent the keyboard from coming up
      }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable
  {
    dRight = null;
    rBounds = null;
    super.finalize();
  }
}
```

**xml**

```
<com.example.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
    …
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@layout/shape"
    android:hint="Enter place,city,state"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/cross" 
/>
```

**activity**

```
CustomEditText et = (CustomEditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
```

see below link for more

[Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

[Setting onClickListner for the Drawable right of an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

from my project - example

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:background="?entry_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_info_avatar" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text"
                style="?primary_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alexander Great"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:text="mobile"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="?secondary_text"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:background="?entry_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >   

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?entry_background"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sv_svyaznoy_contact" />

    </LinearLayout>
```