# Align Images next to RadioButtons in a RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following relative layout code in my Android app:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/selectSound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/micLevelLabel"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radiohighpitched"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiohighpitched"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="High Pitched" 
        android:textColor="@color/android:white"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiofoghorn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fog Horn"
        android:textColor="@color/android:white"
         />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioalarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alert Tone"
        android:textColor="@color/android:white" />
</RadioGroup>



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:onClick="playTone2"
    android:src="@drawable/play_med" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:onClick="playTone3"
    android:src="@drawable/play_med" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/selectSound"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/micLevelLabel"
    android:onClick="playTone1"
    android:src="@drawable/play_med" />
```

It produces a layout that looks like this:

[image: Layout results]

It just so happens to line up correctly because of the image size of the `ImageButtons`. I've recently redesigned the app and the `ImageButtons` on the right hand side no longer line up with the `RadioButtons`.

Is there a more robust way to construct this layout such that the `ImageButtons` always align with the corresponding `RadioButtons`?

Answer (score 3):

If its not mandatory, to use `ImageButton`, you can go with this approach.

What I did was:

Simply used a `drawableight` for all `RadioButton` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="@string/high" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="@string/med" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="@string/low" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

And for their click event, you can get a hint from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135554/1777090)

Hope this helps.