# Click on EditText's drawable right with Espresso

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-espresso

How could be possible to click on EditText's right drawable (check the screenshot)? I have tried several ways but I always get stuck.

```
public static Matcher<View> withEditTextDrawable(final int resourceId) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, EditText>(EditText.class) {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(final EditText editText) {
            // ????

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ");
            description.appendValue(resourceId);
        }
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had to develop this custom action and matcher to test our discard drawables on the right of some text fields, 
[image: discard edittext]
this will click **any drawable** (left, top, right, bottom) of a TextView in an Espresso test.

**Usage:**

```
onView(withId(id)).perform(clickDrawables());
```

**Method:**

```
public static ViewAction clickDrawables()
{
    return new ViewAction()
    {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints()//must be a textview with drawables to do perform
        {
            return allOf(isAssignableFrom(TextView.class), new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class)
            {
                @Override
                protected boolean matchesSafely(final TextView tv)
                {
                    if(tv.requestFocusFromTouch())//get fpocus so drawables become visible
                        for(Drawable d : tv.getCompoundDrawables())//if the textview has drawables then return a match
                            if(d != null)
                                return true;

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void describeTo(Description description)
                {
                    description.appendText("has drawable");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription()
        {
            return "click drawables";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view;
            if(tv != null && tv.requestFocusFromTouch())//get focus so drawables are visible
            {
                Drawable[] drawables = tv.getCompoundDrawables();

                Rect tvLocation = new Rect();
                tv.getHitRect(tvLocation);

                Point[] tvBounds = new Point[4];//find textview bound locations
                tvBounds[0] = new Point(tvLocation.left, tvLocation.centerY());
                tvBounds[1] = new Point(tvLocation.centerX(), tvLocation.top);
                tvBounds[2] = new Point(tvLocation.right, tvLocation.centerY());
                tvBounds[3] = new Point(tvLocation.centerX(), tvLocation.bottom);

                for(int location = 0; location < 4; location++)
                    if(drawables[location] != null)
                    {
                        Rect bounds = drawables[location].getBounds();
                        tvBounds[location].offset(bounds.width() / 2, bounds.height() / 2);//get drawable click location for left, top, right, bottom
                        if(tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, tvBounds[location].x, tvBounds[location].y, 0)))
                            tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, tvBounds[location].x, tvBounds[location].y, 0));
                    }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**This is a refinement I made to select a specific drawable to click:**

**Usage:**

```
onView(withId(id)).perform(new ClickDrawableAction(ClickDrawableAction.Right));
```

**Method:**

```
public static class ClickDrawableAction implements ViewAction
{
    public static final int Left = 0;
    public static final int Top = 1;
    public static final int Right = 2;
    public static final int Bottom = 3;

    @Location
    private final int drawableLocation;

    public ClickDrawableAction(@Location int drawableLocation)
    {
        this.drawableLocation = drawableLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints()
    {
        return allOf(isAssignableFrom(TextView.class), new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class)
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(final TextView tv)
            {
                //get focus so drawables are visible and if the textview has a drawable in the position then return a match
                return tv.requestFocusFromTouch() && tv.getCompoundDrawables()[drawableLocation] != null;

            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description)
            {
                description.appendText("has drawable");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return "click drawable ";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)view;//we matched
        if(tv != null && tv.requestFocusFromTouch())//get focus so drawables are visible
        {
            //get the bounds of the drawable image
            Rect drawableBounds = tv.getCompoundDrawables()[drawableLocation].getBounds();

            //calculate the drawable click location for left, top, right, bottom
            final Point[] clickPoint = new Point[4];
            clickPoint[Left] = new Point(tv.getLeft() + (drawableBounds.width() / 2), (int)(tv.getPivotY() + (drawableBounds.height() / 2)));
            clickPoint[Top] = new Point((int)(tv.getPivotX() + (drawableBounds.width() / 2)), tv.getTop() + (drawableBounds.height() / 2));
            clickPoint[Right] = new Point(tv.getRight() + (drawableBounds.width() / 2), (int)(tv.getPivotY() + (drawableBounds.height() / 2)));
            clickPoint[Bottom] = new Point((int)(tv.getPivotX() + (drawableBounds.width() / 2)), tv.getBottom() + (drawableBounds.height() / 2));

            if(tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, clickPoint[drawableLocation].x, clickPoint[drawableLocation].y, 0)))
                tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, clickPoint[drawableLocation].x, clickPoint[drawableLocation].y, 0));
        }
    }

    @IntDef({ Left, Top, Right, Bottom })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Location{}
}
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer works like a charm on my custom CallToActionEdit text field!

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using the **Material Component** [TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

In your xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:id="@+id/til_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="custom"
            app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_edit_location"
            app:endIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:endIconContentDescription="open map icon">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                tools:text="3 streenasdasdasd"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The trick here is to set the `app:endIconMode="custom"` then add your drawable as u want.

In java class:

you can use the `setEndIconOnClickListener` and do what you want as below:

```
tilLocation.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do click
        }
    });
```

Comment: Simple and superb answer without writing too much of code

Comment: Simplest and elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

For people that have this problem right now as of 1/7/2021 (European format).
I had the same problem and solved it like this:

In your xml, maybe you have something like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/edittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconCheckable="true"
    app:endIconTint="@color/colorSemiTranspBlack"
    app:endIconContentDescription="clear text">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/eddittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

As you saw the above xml code, i added `app:endIconContentDescription="clear text"`.
grab from the xml, `app:endIconContentDescription="clear text"` and add `onView(withContentDescription("clear text")).perform(click());` in your Instrumented test method, in your test class, like:

```
    @Test
    public void testEdittext(){
    onView(withId(R.id.eddittext)).perform(typeText("Type something."));
    onView(withContentDescription("clear text")).perform(click());
    }
```

Forgot to say that this `onView(withId(R.id.note_title)).perform(typeText("Type something."));` is the line that you must first write something in the edittext, so that the end icon(eddittext's right drawable) will show up and then click it.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer from @dareniott .

I just made it in kotlin:

```
import android.graphics.Point
import android.support.annotation.IntDef
import android.support.test.espresso.UiController
import android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.BoundedMatcher
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import org.hamcrest.Description
import org.hamcrest.Matcher
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf

class ClickDrawableAction(@param:Location @field:Location private val drawableLocation: Int) : ViewAction {
    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return allOf(isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java), object : BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
            override fun matchesSafely(tv: TextView): Boolean {
                return tv.requestFocusFromTouch() && tv.compoundDrawables[drawableLocation] != null
            }

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText(DESCRIPTION_HAS_DRAWABLE)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return DESCRIPTION_CLICK_DRAWABLE
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        val tv = view as TextView
        if (tv.requestFocusFromTouch())
        {
            val drawableBounds = tv.compoundDrawables[drawableLocation].bounds
            val clickPoint = arrayOfNulls<Point>(SIZE_CLICK_POINT)
            clickPoint[LEFT] = Point(tv.left + drawableBounds.width() / HALF_DIVISOR, (tv.pivotY + drawableBounds.height() / HALF_DIVISOR).toInt())
            clickPoint[TOP] = Point((tv.pivotX + drawableBounds.width() / HALF_DIVISOR).toInt(), tv.top + drawableBounds.height() / HALF_DIVISOR)
            clickPoint[RIGHT] = Point(tv.right + drawableBounds.width() / HALF_DIVISOR, (tv.pivotY + drawableBounds.height() / HALF_DIVISOR).toInt())
            clickPoint[BOTTOM] = Point((tv.pivotX + drawableBounds.width() / HALF_DIVISOR).toInt(), tv.bottom + drawableBounds.height() / HALF_DIVISOR)
            clickPoint[drawableLocation]?.let { point ->
                if (tv.dispatchTouchEvent(
                                MotionEvent.obtain(
                                        android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                        android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                        point.x.toFloat(),
                                        point.y.toFloat(),
                                        0)
                        )) {
                    tv.dispatchTouchEvent(
                            MotionEvent.obtain(
                                    android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                    android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                                    point.x.toFloat(),
                                    point.y.toFloat(),
                                    0))
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @IntDef(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    annotation class Location

    companion object {
        const val LEFT = 0
        const val TOP = 1
        const val RIGHT = 2
        const val BOTTOM = 3
        const val SIZE_CLICK_POINT = 4
        const val HALF_DIVISOR = 2
        const val DESCRIPTION_HAS_DRAWABLE = "has drawable"
        const val DESCRIPTION_CLICK_DRAWABLE = "click drawable "
    }
}
```