# Android Edittext multiple actions

Tags: android

```
*In android Edittext, i have set drawable left and right, i can make
click actions for drawable left and right but i cant check single
click and double click for it.*

**Multiple actions:**
```

1.left drawable click
        2.right drawable click
        3.single click 
        4.Double click 
        5.Clear text

Comment: Please be more specific so we can help you solve your problem, add some pictures, some code and explain further

Answer (score 0):

You can use GestureDetector. Check this link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html

Comment: I think click and double click can , but i can make above 5 actions using GestureDetector?

Answer (score 0):

There is some other question like you and they get solution.

Thanks to Mr.Hardik4560 who gives some solution in that question.

Please follow this link to get them.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135554

I hope you get solution from this and solve your issue.