# Contact List retrieve result

Tags: android, android-contacts

When i show a android contact list on DialogFragment using startActivityForResult :

```
 contact.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
                return true;
            }
        });

);
```

when the list of contact appear i should click twice on contact or three time until the the list disappear  instead of one click

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        uriContact = data.getData();
        contact.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share more details, onclick implementation ?

Comment: you want to pick more than one contact or just single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using on touch listener use on click listener. 
Your on touch is event is called thrice. (For touch down, touch up and cancel). 
If you want to use onTouch only, then put a if condition with `event==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` or `event==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Comment: in reality i want to add an event click on right drawable i don't find a solution

Comment: I think for that you can refer to this answer. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistner-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext)
@MohamedMellal