# How to perform click listener on EditText DrawableRight?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to click on EditText DrawableRight and then open items list without array adapter. How it is possible ?

Comment: Have you tried this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135447/setting-onclicklistener-for-the-drawable-right-of-an-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a drawableRight, why not just use an ImageButton and an EditText inside of a RelativeLayout?