# How to place button inside of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, imagebutton

I want to place an image button inside of EditText, but I don't have Idea please tell me how to do so as shown in the figure . Thanks

[image]

Comment: are you want click on this image?

Comment: use EditText's android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"

Comment: I have mentioned that this is an image button

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If You dont want click on that Image, Then you can use `drawableRight` property for EditText..

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
```

If you want click then use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter search key" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for this reply but I want to the image be like clickable Button

Comment: this works but does not meet to my need because it shows the background color of button and border as well, I only want the transparent image..

Comment: @ArshadAliSoomro use transperant image as background

Comment: No, This layout is wrong. what if we took EditText at the bottom or any random place?

Comment: @CapDroid ...If I use your way of designing xml, the user text hides behind the imageview placed on the top. Do you have any idea, how to achieve this with restricting the text to go beyond the limit.

Comment: this donot align the image to right of the EditText.

Answer (score 36):

If you want such layout and also image as clickable then you can do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    </EditText>
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how to add click event on this Image, please

Comment: Map imageview by id in your Activity class and set Listener to it [See clickListener](http://start-jandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/android-multiple-screen-example.html)

Comment: how to keep my text from going behind the `ImageView`?

Comment: In your XML for edittext, use `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:paddingRight="50dp"` to prevent your text from going behind the image button on the right

Answer (score 20):

In Material, there is that underline under EditText. In most applications the icons appear **inside** that underlining.

[image]

For that purpose, just use padding

```
android:paddingEnd = "@dimen/my_button_size"
```

Don't forget paddingRight for sub 4.2 versions.

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
   ...
   <EditText
   ...
   android:id="@+id/my_text_edit"
   android:textAlignment = "viewStart"
   android:paddingEnd = "@dimen/my_button_size"
   android:paddingRight = "@dimen/my_button_size"
   .../>

   <ImageButton 
   ....
   android:layout_width="@dimen/my_button_size" 
   android:layout_height="@dimen/my_button_size"
   android:layout_alignEnd="@id/my_text_edit"
   android:layout_alignRight="@id/my_text_edit"/>
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

It will limit the text to the image and the image will not overlap the text, however long the text may be.

Answer (score 7):

My solution will fit all screen sizes without the `editText` going "behind" the `imageButton`. This also uses android resources, so you do not need to provide your own icon or string resource. Copy and paste this snippet wherever you would like a search bar:

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
  
   <EditText
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:hint="@android:string/search_go"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Restult:**

[image]

Comment: A bunch of thanks for your typical answer, hope in future it will help some newbies and me as well...! But I recommend to use [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html)

Comment: @ArshadAli Ah yeah. That one is better.

Comment: i wasted much time in doing this. thank you. how comes android makes our life difficult in doing this kind of simple thing?

Answer (score 5):

you can Use the Below Code :

**`android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"`**

Answer (score 4):

How about placing it in a RelativeLayout like this ?:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- EditText for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search whatever..."
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/magnifyingglass"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextColorCustom"/>

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/xbutton"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Also this way you´ll be able to handle the visibility of the Button (GONE / VISIBLE) in code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is the style for @style/EditTextColorCustom?

Comment: Hi, it´s just a custom style for the EditText (styles.xml) and the code I use in this particular case is: <style name="EditTextColorCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

Place your EditText inside a linear layout (horizontal) and add a Image Button next to it (0 padding). Setting the background color of EditText and ImageButton will blend in.

Answer (score 1):

There's solution with clickable compound drawable. It's working very well - I have tested it

[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295931/1592183)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple I feel. Use relative layout as your parent layout.
Place the editText to left and ImageButton to the right using either,

- alignRight property for the ImageButton
- by specifying the layout weight for each of the fields

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer the ripple effect doesn't work, it stays behind the button in the back.

This example has 2 buttons in the textbox.
The ripple effect works because the parent layout has

```
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

To make sure the ripple works and doesn't stay on the back, set the imagebutton's parent background to transparent.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_textbox"
                android:hint="text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/clear"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Or you can also wrap your button in a frame layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >
<ImageButton ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you want to place `ImageButton` to achieve, which can be done with simple property of `EditText`

> android:drawableRight="your drawable"

Can't it be work for you?

Comment: OK that may work but my need was to click on the image button and get some action done on it as well!

Answer (score -2):

Use the android:drawableLeft property on the EditText.

```
<EditText
    ...     
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" />
```