# Removing default search icon from SearchView widget

Tags: android, android-widget, searchview

How can i remove default search icon which appears as a hint in SearchView widget(not in actionbar)?Through styles i can change the icon but i can't find a way to remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 10):

It's Worked......

```
ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

ViewGroup linearLayoutSearchView =(ViewGroup) searchViewIcon.getParent();
linearLayoutSearchView.removeView(searchViewIcon);
```

Comment: Best answer of the lot

Comment: For androidx users use this 
`ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
searchViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 5):

For me it only worked this:

```
ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
magImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
magImage.setImageDrawable(null);
```

[@sector11's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530742/removing-default-search-icon-from-searchview-widget#34614983) almost got it, but still you need to add the line `magImage.setImageDrawable(null)` because taking a look at `SearchView.java` in Github,specifically the method [updateViewsVisibility](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/d6e47228c44aaadb0d4518da6db5c3f5dffda1ab/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#L904), you can see that it constantly gets its visibility updated

**Extract from GitHub**

```
if (mCollapsedIcon.getDrawable() == null || mIconifiedByDefault) {
    iconVisibility = GONE;
} else {
    iconVisibility = VISIBLE;
}
mCollapsedIcon.setVisibility(iconVisibility);
```

Answer (score 4):

For androidx SearchView just use `app:searchIcon="@null"`

Comment: only works for the plain view, once the search bar is clicked the icons still there

Answer (score 3):

As of now you should use

```
ImageView magImage = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
magImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle"  parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
     <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Never use direct android ids to find the view because in future if the ids change, your code will not work. Always use standard ways to solve the problems instead of a workaround.
for more info refer this [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can override it:

```
    int searchImgId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView searchImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);


searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If your search view is in layout then please use EditText with close button:

https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/develop/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java

If you want to create your own then use frame layout and add text change listener to mange visibility of close or cancel button.

there are few discussion regarding search view in UI:

[How to create EditText with cross(x) button at end of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355096/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it)

[How to place button inside of edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151366/how-to-place-button-inside-of-edit-text)

If you want to show search list then use AutoCompleteTextView instead of EditText.

you can read tutorial from below link:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

2.http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/autocompletetextview/android-auto-complete-example/

3.http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105&aaid=127

I hope it will work.

Comment: it gives NullPointerException on `searchImage.setLayoutParams`..i placed this inside onCreate() of activity

Comment: onCreate(), where you write your code to prepare all view.

Comment: getting nullpointerexception on `searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: are you sure `android:id/search_mag_icon` is correct?

Comment: my searchview widget is iconified..when i click on icon it expands ..i am NOT using `setIconifiedByDefault(false)`

Comment: You want to remove search icon or not ?

Comment: Yeah I want to remove search icon from expandable search view

Comment: Instead of `context.getResources()` i tried `getApplicationContext().getResources()` ,`getBaseContext().getResources()` and just `getResources()` but none of them worked..What should be there in `context`?

Comment: My SearchView is NOT a part of action bar..maybe I need to use something different there

Comment: My searchView is in xml layout NOT in menu layout

Comment: but i need to display suggestion list also.i have used editext with cross button previously where suggestion list is not required..but here suggestion list is required

Comment: Then use autocomplete textview instead of EditText.

Answer (score 2):

please set this SearchView in your code

`android:paddingLeft="-16dp"   // this line is remove the space of icon`

`android:paddingStart="-16dp" // // this line is remove the space of icon`

`android:searchIcon="@null"  // this line to remove the search icon`

`android:closeIcon="@null"  // this line to remove the close icon`

```
 <SearchView
                        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:id="@+id/search"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:paddingLeft="-16dp"
                        android:paddingStart="-16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:searchIcon="@null"
                        android:closeIcon="@null"
                        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme"
                        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                        android:queryHint="@string/hint">

                        <requestFocus />

                    </SearchView>
```