# Want to remove search icon as hint from the searchView

Tags: android, searchview

```
    int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    ImageView magImage = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(magId);
    magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    magImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I'm using this above code, but it is not removing the `search` icon. I've set

```
 mSearchView.setIconified(false);
```

Not understading that why it is still showing the icon.

Comment: Check this link it already asked... [Removing default search icon from SearchView widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530742/removing-default-search-icon-from-searchview-widget) [Remove the SearchIcon as hint in the searchView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323990/remove-the-searchicon-as-hint-in-the-searchview)

Comment: @ShishirKatiyar I've checked that link already, it is not working in my case

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late , but if anyone else wants to solve this problem , then

1) In style.xml add

```
<style name="MyToolbar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/searchStyle</item>
</style>
```

If your min API level >= 21

```
<style name="searchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:queryHint">@string/search</item>
    <item name="android:searchIcon">@null</item>  
</style>
```

else

```
<style name="searchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

2) Finally add your style in the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
        />
```

Comment: Thank you, after an endless search the only answer that worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you use appcompat-v7 > 24, you should try this

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                ...
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:searchIcon="@null"
                />
```