# How to handle click events on a drawable within an TextView?

Tags: android, click, icons, textview

I have the same problem as discussed on [Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext), but I use `TextView` instead of `EditText`. When I click on the `TextView`, the method `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` is called. Is it possible to handle a click only on the icon?

Comment: you can use TouchDelegate....

Comment: @AnandTiwari, I found [this code](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/ListViewTipsAndTricks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would be a better idea to use a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. Of course, it leads to a more complex layout structure, but I'd prefer two widgets in an XML file rather than [too much Java code dealing with the widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv"
    android:text="@string/long_text"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_go" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is pretty much the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853024/1318939): use the event coordinates and determine if they are within the drawable's bounds. If they are, perform your action. I don't think there are any major differences between `TextView` and `EditText` in this respect.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I have another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19834049/1065835)