# Click event for Android EditText Right Drawable

Tags: android

I had an EditText for which I added left n right drawable. I am unable to handle click evnt for right drwable . How to handle click events for android right drawable icon.

Comment: Post your code..without code its hard to say anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

Answer (score 3):

you need to add touchevent replace onclick and you can use below code

```
mEditTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length()>0){
            mEditTextSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_delete), null);
        }else{
            mEditTextSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_search), null);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
mEditTextSearch.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(mEditTextSearch.getCompoundDrawables()[2]!=null){
                if(event.getX() >= (mEditTextSearch.getRight()- mEditTextSearch.getLeft() - mEditTextSearch.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {
                    mEditTextSearch.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what if users want to delete letters one by one instead of whole text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can handle an event for leftDrawable or rightDrawable. You can handle events for the whole view. If you want to do this you have two choices:

- Extend your own version of EditText or
- Put your drawable as an independent ImageView

Answer (score 0):

as in: [Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

> ```
> editComment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
>     @Override
>     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>         final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
>         final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
>         final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
>         final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
>
>         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
>             if(event.getX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width()))
>             {
>                 // your action here
>
>              return true;
>             }
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> });
> ```