# Create tags in edit text?

Tags: android

I am trying to create tags but still cant find single login for that .

Android how I can create tag from a text like this site when I write android it is showig highlighted with cross button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to write clearly understandable questions. From what I understood you want an `EditText` that contains tokens. You can do so using one of many open source libraries, such as this one: https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

In xml, an edittext with a drawable mentioned:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>
</EditText>
```

Add textwatcher to that edittext and check its text if that matches any of a bunch of String. If so, just show the drawable, else set the drawable to null.

See this:

```
EditText msg;
msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
msg.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

msg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (msg.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("android"))
        msg.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0);
        else
        msg.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } 

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

You would need to customize if you want the whole text and image in another box like a tag is shown.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext) for handling of click event of a drawable inside edittext.

Hope this gives you a start.