# Highlighting words in a TextView with a View like in Gmail app?

Tags: android, view, textview, highlight

Does anybody know, how is email address highlighted in Gmail app on Android?
Here is the screen show of what I mean:
[image]

I know, that text can be highlighted using span, or HTML code, but what should I do, if there is custom View?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you mean something like [this](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library)?

Comment: @PurpleDroid yes I am looking for something like this, but TextView, not EditText

Comment: Not possible to customize that? I haven't worked so no idea.

Comment: @PurpleDroid and I don't need completion. Anyway post your comment as answer and I'll consider it as right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with [Chips Edittext library](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library) and customize it to work for textview.

If you don't want to use this library, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24203341/1777090). The similar behavior could be obtained for textview easily.