# OnClickListener to TextView's drawableRight in Bubble/Tag TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, touch-event, onitemclicklistener

I have used [this link](http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/) with [this project link](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Spannable) to create TagTextViews.

I've modified this a bit since I only need a single String per item, and the result is as follows:
[image]

In the code of the link there is a `ClickableSpan` with an `onClick` that deleted the 'Tag'. So if you click anywhere on the 'Tag', it will delete this Tag-item.

What I want instead is:

- Only delete the 'Tag' when the X (`android:drawableRight` of the TextView) is clicked.
- And if the item itself is clicked do something else.

Here below are the parts of the code in the link that is relevant to my problem:

custom_textview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/et_textview"
    ...
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    ... />
```

In TagTextView.java:

```
BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = getBitmapFromText(userInputString);
bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable), spanEnd, startIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
this.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO: If the tiny X is clicked on the Item:
            deleteString();
        // TODO: else (If the item itself (so not the tiny X) is clicked):
            // Do something else
    }
};
ssb.setSpan(clickSpan, spanEnd, startIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I did find [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext) which uses an `OnTouchListener`. But since I'm working with multiple List-items and there isn't an `OnItemTouchListener` in Android, I don't know how to correctly implement this in the `ClickableSpan#onClick()`.

---

Edit:

Ok, it turned out I made a pretty stupid mistake. The `getBitmapFromText(String)` creates a single Bitmap from the TextView that has the `android:drawableRight`. So the `ImageSpan(bitmapDrawable)` that is used in the code is the entire 'Tag'.

Since the existing code also deletes a Tag when it's backspaced, I now use that as the delete function and when I click the 'Tag' itself do my own method. In addition I also deleted the `android:drawableRight` to prevent confusion from my app users.

TL;DR: I changed it to: Click 'Tag' = Do something I want; Backspace the 'Tag' = The delete method.

Sorry for the confusion this may have caused, since I didn't included the entire piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

set the View that the constructor is associated to the X not the entire widget

constructor:
public abstract void onClick (View widget)

widget needs to point at the x widget, not the tag

Comment: I know what you mean, but how to implement this in the code provided by the first link in my question? And the X is a default Android-Drawable added by `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"` in the TextView, so it's not a separated View which I can easily pass through to the onClick as parameter.

Comment: it seems as though this tutorial will help you, can't go deep in and play with it now but setSpan needs to be pointed only at the x through the difference in image and clickable spans, http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/

Comment: that's the tutorial I used. The link in my question is the same link as the github-link at the bottom of that tutorial. I've placed a comment there, so perhaps the original blog-poster knows how to easily fix this and will response soon.

Comment: the relative difference used in here sb.setSpan(clickSpan, sb.length() - contactname.length(),
               sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);   doesnt seem to be in your code( cannot tell the values of span end and start index) but that is theoretically what should account for your issue

Comment: That's the second ClickableSpan. In the entire `CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView` class of the blog it is called twice, once in the `addSpanText-method` (which indeed is `sb.setSpan(clickSpan, sb.length() - contactname.length(), sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` like you said) and once in the `addOrCheckSpannable` (which is the one I copied to my question).

Comment: (from your variable names: spanEnd, and startIndex  it looks like you have those two values mixed up, first value is the index where the span begins(total length- text field length) second argument should be where it ends(total length)   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Comment: I copied that from the blog and you're right it's a bit confusing that he named them 'end, start' instead of 'start, end'. But I just debugged it and `spanEnd = 0` and `startIndex = 5`. So even though he named them confusing :S (and I will change this..) the values inside or correct.

Comment: right so you have it beginning at 0, and ending at 5, which are the index values to cover the entire bubble, you only want it to cover the X at the end of the bubble so the start value should not be 0(make a method to set span end to something different than 0 check line 192, he uses the commas to do this quite nicely there