# Can a Voice action button be added within edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, voice-recognition

How to create a voice button within edittext like google search with voice button. see below image url like that i want. any one suggest me.

[Sample Image EditText with Mic](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zlydqpiW0No/VBAY1L4mSZI/AAAAAAAAAq0/lXbtRscvvF4/s0/voic.PNG)

Comment: You can create customView that vill extend View class and inside that view add EditText and Button. Then in XML use Tag View to reserve space for your controll and you can add it programatically in code behind. It would be nested like <View><CustomView/><View/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_edt"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_Contact"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number|text|numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Mic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/mic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This way you can make a `clickListener` of Mic to do some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an edittext in xml and apply the right drwable for the edittext. This will look like the same. hope this piece of code will help you...

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_diesel_filtername"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:drawableRight="your mic icon" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext hope this link will guide you more...

Comment: But `DrawableRight` click listener is not possible.