# Click event on EditText's drawableRight not working properly?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contacts, android-drawable

I need to open phone's contact book on the click of `EditText`'s `drawableRight`. Click event on `drawableRight` is working fine But the problem is, when I click/touch on anywhere on `EditText` it is also execute click event and open contact list.

I take help for manage click event on `drawableRight` from here [Please check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

I don't want to open contact list when I click on `EditText`, I only want to open it when I click `drawableRight` (image). So how solve this problem?

[image: drawbleRight]

Here is my code:

```
EditText mobile_number;
mobile_number = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number1);
mobile_number.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    if(event.getRawX()>=(mobile_number.getRight()-mobile_number.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width()));
                    {

                         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_two1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout_one1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:hint="Enter Your Mobile Number"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/mobile_number1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/editbox_icon"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add to layoute 1 is edit text and an other is image. then you set ontuchlistner in the image\

Comment: change the last `return true;` to `return false;`, then test again.

Comment: @John Changing it to false does not effect, any thing ........I already tried this.

Comment: @Destro I don't want this kind of solution. Means I dont want add image in side of edittext in different or same layout .........I want to use drawableRight in edit text.

Comment: Make custom edittext and implement listener for right drawable icon.

Comment: Please read my question again ........ I add a reference link from where I am using this code.

Comment: I have given suggestion to implement !

Comment: @DevendraDagur I have tested it again, it worked, just chage the last `return` to `false`. Also you have to remove the comma `;` at the end of `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using getRawX(), try replacing that line with

```
if (event.getX() >= (mobile_number.getWidth() - mobile_number
        .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
```

EDIT: I believe View.getRight() returns the position of the right edge of the View relative to its parent, while TouchEvent.getRawX() returns the absolute X position on the screen.

EDIT AGAIN TO DEMONSTRATE MY POINT:

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.meremammal.www.edittextdrawable.MainActivity">

    <!-- This layout is only here to demonstrate a situation that breaks the usage of getRawX() -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mEditText;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        mEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private float touchX = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int drawableLeft = mEditText.getRight() - mEditText
                        .getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width();
                // This detects the location of touch on ACTION_DOWN, but because it is
                // using getRawX() and getRight() and the EditText's parent is not at the
                // left of the screen, it will respond when clicked in the middle of the
                // EditText. Instead, use getX() and EditText.getWidth()
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getRawX() >= drawableLeft) {
                    touchX = event.getRawX();
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && touchX >= drawableLeft) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked Button",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    touchX = 0;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return mEditText.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: YA ........I put semicolon by mistake at the end of if statement.......OOPs........  May be IDE should provide warning or something for this kind of minor mistakes. My Bad.

Comment: Does that mean your existing condition would have worked without the semicolon?

Comment: I think the problem of this issue is the redundancy semicolon `;` at the end of  `if` statements. not `getX()` or `getRawX()`

Comment: I still feel as if getRawX() will not work properly if the parent view is not at the left edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the right image as far my knowledge, unless you create custom EditText class. I suggest to use a RelativeLayout, with one editText and one imageView, and set OnClickListener over the image view as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSearch"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:ems="10"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btnsearch" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Linear layout with horizontal orientation and add a edit-text and image-view with proper weight..

Then Give on click for each item separately.....

Answer (score 0):

Just chage the last `return` to `false`. Also you have to remove the comma `;` at the end of if statement.