# image button works only if click twice

Tags: android, onclick

**Details:**

I've an `EditText` in my activity with right drawable(calender icon). If I click on either `EditText` or on calendar icon `datepicker` dialog box should open.

**Problem:**

If I click on `EditText` `datepicker` dialog box is opened properly, but if I click on the `Calendar` icon at first time nothing is happening. If I click on the same icon one more time, then `datepicker` dialog is open.

I already implemented ontouch for right drawable given below:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mValidationId = (Integer) v.getTag();

                if (mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT] != null
                        && !isErrorIconDisplayedForCalendarIcon) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (mEditText.getRight() - mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT]
                            .getBounds().width())) {
                        isErrorIconDisplayedForCalendarIcon = mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_DATEOFBIRTH;
                        ViewUtils.hideVirturalKeyboard(mEditText);
                        mListener.OnErrorIconClick(mValidationId);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        HideErrorIcon();
                        if (mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_DATEOFBIRTH) {
                            mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
                                mListener.OnCalendarIconClick();
                            ViewUtils.hideVirturalKeyboard(mEditText);
                        } else {
                            v.requestFocus();
                            ViewUtils.showVirturalKeyboard(mContext.getApplicationContext());

                            if (mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_USERNAME ||
                                    mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_PASSWORD) {
                                RegistrationUserCredentialsController controller = (
                                        (RegistrationUserCredentialsController) mDsmApplication
                                                .getController(RegistrationUserCredentialsController.TAG));
                                if (controller != null) {
                                    controller.OnRegistrationItemEditStart(mValidationId);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    isErrorIconDisplayedForCalendarIcon = false;
                    if (mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_DATEOFBIRTH) {
                        mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
                        mListener.OnCalendarIconClick();
                        ViewUtils.hideVirturalKeyboard(mEditText);
                    } else {
                        if (mCurrentEditText != null && !mEditText.equals(mCurrentEditText)) {
                            mListener.OnRegistrationItemEditCompleted(
                                    mCurrentEditText.getText().toString(), (Integer) mCurrentEditText.getTag()
                            );
                        }
                        mCurrentEditText = (CustomTextInputEditText) v;
                        v.requestFocus();
                        ViewUtils.showVirturalKeyboard(mContext.getApplicationContext());

                        if (mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_USERNAME ||
                                mValidationId == RegistrationValidator.VALIDATE_PASSWORD) {
                            RegistrationUserCredentialsController controller = (
                                    (RegistrationUserCredentialsController) mDsmApplication
                                            .getController(RegistrationUserCredentialsController.TAG));
                            if (controller != null) {
                                controller.OnRegistrationItemEditStart(mValidationId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
```

In the above code, I have an issue with date of birth related `Edittext`. If I click on right drawable underline color of `Edittext` is changing and after second click, the date picker dialog is open.

Comment: visit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33996656/6021469 
May you got your solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Try below may help you.It works for me.

```
mEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= (mEditText.getRight() - mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                // your action here

             return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: hai shweta same thing is already there in my code which I have posted know?

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml for that activity

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

Comment: hai sunil thanks for help but it is not working for me

Comment: This answer is nowhere related to what the OP is asking.