# Make ExploreByTouch focus a drawable?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout

Maybe this is a stupid question but I'm new to Android and I'd appreciate any help you could lend me. I have a drawable (not a button) on the right side of an EditTextValidator (I did not create this layout, I'm only doing some maintenance tasks). Is there a way to make the TalkbBack say a certain word when clicking only on that drawable? It's a question icon, and when clicked it sends the user to a screen that contains information. As far as I know, a drawable can't be focused nor it can interact with the user. The program uses a custom event handler that detects when the user clicks on the right side of the EditText to start the Info Activity.

I hope this is enough information, if not please tell me and I'll try to elaborate more. Sorry for my bad English.

EDIT: The question is NOT how to start the Info Activity by clicking the icon, that is already done. What I want is the TalkBack to say "Help" when the user finds the icon when using ExploreByTouch.

Comment: Yes, every UI element could have an action listener, you need to register one to this element and it will work. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext

Comment: Sorry, I might have not expressed my problem correctly, I added a clarification. Thanks for your answer.