# How to disable paste in onClickListener for the Drawable right of an EditText Android (inside icon EditText)

Tags: android, android-widget

I have `EditText` and icon inside it

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myedittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/microphone"/>
```

I Set `onClickListener` for the `Drawable` right of an `EditText`

```
myeditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (myeditText.getRight() - myeditText
      .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {  
                    // your action here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "speak",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

when I click to icon right of `EditText` Toast show me and work, but show me paste option on `EditText` too.
how can I remove paste when icon in right clicked?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's already about 3 years. However, for someone like me that might face this challenge: The solution is to also return true in ACTION_DOWN but only call the listener on ACTION_DOWN, returning true as well. In this case, you first check the region clicked corresponds with that of the icon, before proceeding to check action up or down
Something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;


        if (event.getRawX() >= (myeditText.getRight() - myeditText
                .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // your action here
                listener.onClick(v);
                return true;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing from `ACTION_UP` to `ACTION_DOWN` gave effect. Of course, behaviour sligtly changed. And cursor still jumps to the end of a text.

Answer (score 1):

Just set **android:longClickable="false"** to editbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext) question and see how to disable the **paste**.

But I'd suggest something else, instead of disabling paste, you can probably do this in a different way. Looking at whatsapp's **microphone button + `EditText`** placement, I notice that they're two different elements, and this is what you may do. Wrap your `EditText` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and place a button with a microphone at the right end. I hope you can manage to make it work, and that you understand my idea.