# Material Design Input Text

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Is there a way to create an input field that looks like the ones on this image - Icon on the left, input on the right - using only the default `TextInputLayout`?

I've tried several combinations, and the icon always stays inside the `TextInputEditText`. I've tried changing the `TextInputLayout` orientation to horizontal but it didn't work as well. Is there anyway of doing this without placing an `ImageView` and an `EditText` inside of another `ViewGroup`?

Below is the code I used to create an input field, but with the icon remains inside the `TextInputEditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_bank_card_back_grey_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/default_padding"            
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Material Design Input Text]

Comment: I would assume that's a `TableLayout`, with three columns for icon, field, and `Spinner`, but use `uiautomatorviewer` to examine the structure of that UI and find out.

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext

Answer (score 2):

Does this fit the bill ? :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:hint="code"
        android:text="0044"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:minWidth="350dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cross"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/cross"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textColorHint="#ff0000"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

image from code:
[image: image from code]

Comment: Nop. This is the same as I did. If you look at the attached image, you can see that there's no underline on the icon. I can achieve something similar using a LinearLayout and an ImageView, but I think there's a better way of doing this. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @JeffersonTavares That's just how compound drawables work in `EditText`s. To change that behavior, you'd have to subclass the `EditText` class you're using, or do some rather clunky reflection, or use some padding hack on the background drawable, etc. It's just easier to use a separate `ImageView`, which is what the image you've posted appears to be doing.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm gonna close this question because it won't be of much help to other users. As the TextInputLayout inherits from LinearLayout, it should be a simple and easy task to wrap an ImageView and an EditText inside of it, but sometimes things just doesn't work as expected, I guess xD

Comment: Yes @Mike M is right, I thought you had some kind of bug with padding (text over writing image). So android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText might have helped (I did not spot you were already using it, it was very late at night ;O)). It (EditText) is functioning as I expect it to. Yes do as you yourself suggest, it's more flexible anyway.