# How do I assign an id to a drawable in text view in the xml file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How do I assign an id to a drawable in text view in the xml file.

The three dots is the drawable.

[image]

So I can find it by id.

```
findViewById<??????>(R.id.id_of_drawable)
```

Comment: You don't  Drawables don't keep an id, because they may not come from a resource at all.  What are you actually trying to do, and are you using a right drawable of a textview, or is it a separate view?

Comment: In the text view I've added app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_more". I want to add setOnClickListener to the ic_more.

Comment: You can't.  You can only put a click listener on a view.  If you want to do that, you can't use an end drawable-  you need to use a separate ImageView, or you need the click handler to be on the entire TextView.

Comment: When I used ImageView in RelativeLayout or LinearLayout the Image was invisible.

Comment: Probably this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194441/10248593

Comment: Then you did something wrong with the layout.  That's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an image view next to the text view.
android:srcCompat made the image invisible.
When I changed it to android:src it worked.